# Javascript code semantics

Tags: javascript, semantics

```
if(myVar = img.parent('a').length > 0){
    var Y = 1;
}else{
    var Y = 2;
}
```

When I run this code myVar (being announced for the first time) takes the value of `img.parent('a').length > 0` and becomes either `false` or `true` depending on the case.

*First Question:*
Is this a correct way of defining **myVar**?

*Second Question:*
Am I defining **Y** for the second time? Is my second `'var'` excess?
i.e. should i just write `Y = 2;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question: IMO, using an assignment on the condition of the `if` statement, might cause confusion, also if `myVar` is not declared previously with the `var` statement it might become a global variable.

Second question: No, you aren't [re-declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864013/is-there-any-advantage-of-redeclaring-javascript-variables) `Y` a second time, actually `Y` is defined *before* any assignment, it is *hoisted* to the top of its enclosing scope.

This is how actually `var` behaves in your code:

```
var Y; // declared and initialized with `undefined`

if (myVar = img.parent('a').length > 0) {
  Y = 1; // assignment
} else {
  Y = 2; // assignment
}
```

You can observe this behavior with the following example:

```
var Y = 'foo';
(function () {
  alert(Y); //alerts `undefined`
  var Y;
})();
```

As you see, the `alert` is before the `var` declaration in that function, but since the `var` statement is *hoisted*, the `Y` variable from this new scope is set up before the execution, when the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process takes place.

The most straight forward approach, would be to declare and assign `myVar`:

```
var Y, myVar = img.parent('a').length > 0;

if (myVar) {
  Y = 1;
} else {
  Y = 2;
}
// Or Y = myVar ? 1 : 2;
```

Or even shorter, in a single `var` statement:

```
var myVar = img.parent('a').length > 0,
    Y = myVar ? 1 : 2;
//...
```