# for loop declaration, are those two statements equal?

Tags: javascript

#### Statement 1

`var i = 0;`
`for (; i < 10 ; i++);`

#### Statement 2

`for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++);`

Are those two statements equal?

Comment: Yes they are equal and will work in the same way.

Comment: Yep, they are equal. All members in [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) are optional.

Comment: @Teemu If all members in the for loop are optional, Does that not infact mean you could just use for(); and it would still be valid, however utterly useless that would be

Comment: @LiamSorsby Actually the semicolons are required, then it would be just an infinite loop.

Comment: @Teemu are there any known usages of the for loop with no parameters but semi-colons. It would be rather interesting to see.

Comment: You could still `break;` out of a infinite loop: `var i=0; for(;;){i++; if(i >= 10){break;}}`

Comment: @LiamSorsby You can use it where ever an infinite loop is needed, for example instead of `while(true){}`. Ofcourse nobody wants really infinite loops, but the conditions for breaking the loop can be checked within the body of the loop, as Cerbrus has shown above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variables declare outside or inside loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, no difference between the 2 examples, functionally.

However, statement 2 can cause confusion. This is because `i` is not scoped to the `for` block, it's accessible outside of that `for` loop, which can result in a polluted global scope.

Just make sure you keep track of your variables when using them like statement 1.
Personally, I prefer something like this:

```
var i;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    // Do stuff
}

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    // Do other stuff
}
```

This way, you'll always have your iterator properly set.

Comment: in both statements i will be global, but i agree on confusion

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific differences. Javascript's variable's scope is different from other languages like C#. This is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465211/javascript-loop-variable-scope)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Sid M, Agreed. But, the answer to the question is already there. And describing the same thing again from another post (as if that I found it) is IMHO "plagiarism"