# ng-file-upload with multiple file upload and progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want to upload multiple files to rails server and want to show separate progress bar for each files. I am using ng-file-upload to upload files. files are getting uploaded but it showing progress for only last file and not for others..I am attaching my code. please help.

Angular controller code:

```
$scope.upload_file = function() {

    var files = $scope.files;
    var uploadUrl = base_url+"/upload_image";
    var job_id = $scope.directive.id;
    if(current_user.role == "third_party_vendor" || current_user.role == "employee")
    {
        var source = current_user.user_login+"-"+current_user.role;   
    }
    else
    {
        var source = $scope.dataObj.source["user_login"]+"-"+$scope.dataObj.source["role"];
    }

    if(job_id === "" || job_id === undefined || files === undefined || files === ""){
        error_notification("Please select a job and a file.");
        return;
    }
    hideLoader();
    $("#upload_resume_queue").modal('show');

    var formData = new Array();
    formData['job_id'] = job_id;
    formData['context'] = "inside_page";
    formData['source'] = source;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      console.log(file.name);
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: uploadUrl, 
        data:{myObj: formData},
        file: file, 
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        //console.log('percent: ' +parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));


                file.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total)


      }).success(function(responseText) {
        hideLoader();
        try{
            var response = responseText;
        }catch(e){
            error_notification("Invalid Excel file Imported.");
            return;
        }
        if(response.status==='wrong_content_type')
            error_notification("Please upload a valid file format.",0);
        if(response.status==='job_application_present'){
            $scope.duplicate = true;
            $scope.jobID = job_id;
            $scope.user_id = response.user_id;
            $scope.application_id = response.application_id;
            //showModal('#duplicate_application_modal');
            error_notification("Job Application already present for this user and job.",0);
        }
        if(response.status==='invalid_email')
            error_notification("The email in the resume is an invalid one.",0);
        if(response.status==='success')
            success_notification("The uploaded resume has been parsed.",0);
      });
    }
  };
```

Html code:

```
<input type="file" class="required file_browse" ng-file-select="" ng-model="files" multiple />
```

Comment: Awesome links.  Its helpful for me and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*I am not able test the following but, I think I found what is wrong.*

In JavaScript variables are scoped to functions. So, in your for loop you change value of `file` in `var file = files[i];` line. At the end, after `for` loop finished the value of `file` is the last file.

At some point `.progress` event is fired by `ng-file-upload` to notify you about progress (for one of the files). And you update the status, but, since `file` has the value of the last file, not the one you expected to be, the last file's status is being updated.

That's why only the last file updated. To solve, you need to access the correct `file` for each `progress` event. To do this, you can keep `file` variable using an anonymous function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  (function(file) {
    console.log(file.name);
    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
      url: uploadUrl, 
      data:{myObj: formData},
      file: file, 
    }).progress(function(evt) {
      //console.log('percent: ' +parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      file.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total)
    }).success(function(responseText) {
      // the other stuff
    });
  })(files[i])
}
```

In your code there may be other problems related to variable scopes and javascript event loop. For more information please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465211/javascript-loop-variable-scope).