# Why does console.log outside "for" loop print out an "extra" number?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm working on some simple Javascript codes and there is something I'm not sure I understand. When I input this code,

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    console.log(x);
}
```

naturally, it prints out 0 to 4. But if I add

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    console.log(x);
}
console.log(x);
```

then it will print out 0 to 5. Why does it print out 5?

Comment: What do you expect it to print out? Anyway, the loop runs while `x < 5`, so when `x` becomes `5`, it exits, but `x` is still `5` after that. If you’re wondering why `x` is still in scope at all, that’s because `var`-declared variables have function scope in JavaScript, rather than block scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally normal!

The last iteration was not the 5th one (which printed "4", as expected), but the 6th one, where it found that `x` value ("5") exceeded the defined limit.

Since `for` statement is not a closure, `var x` stills exists at the loop end, so it prints its value.

Answer (score 4):

It had to check and see if `x` was greater than `5`, or else the loop would never end.

If `x` is equal to `4`, it runs the loop and increments `x` by `1` again, making `x` return `5`. When it checks to see if `x` is less than `5`, it evaluates to `false` and ends the loop.

For this reason, when the loop ends, `x` is equal to `5`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand For as short version of While.

```
for(<start>, <condition>, <change>) {
    <loop>
}
<end>
```

Is equal to:

```
<start>
while(<condition>){
    <loop>
    <change>
}
<end>
```

You can see, that `<change>` is after `<loop>` but somehow before next `<condition>` check.

- check condition
- make changes
- check condition
- make changes
- check condition, fails, exit loop

And you can see, that changes where applied.

### If you don't want this to happend

Use `do-while` loop. But in some cases you have to check condition in the first place. Ex.:

```
<start>
if(<condition>){
    do {
        <loop>
        <change>
    } while(<condition>);
}
<end>
```

*There are other methods, but it's just syntax, not algorythm change.*

Answer (score 0):

Some additional considerations. This explains why 'x' is still in scope for the last console.log(x). Scope might not behave this way in other languages.

See the [MDN for the "initialization parameters" of a for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Parameters):

> An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable
>   declaration. Typically used to initialize a counter variable. This
>   expression may optionally declare new variables with the var keyword.
>   These variables are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same
>   scope the for loop is in. The result of this expression is discarded.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block):

> Important: JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced
>   with a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the
>   effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other
>   words, block statements do not introduce a scope. Although
>   "standalone" blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use
>   standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think
>   they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java.

(This is pulled from answers by [insertusernamehere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456376/insertusernamehere) and user2718994 from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465211/javascript-loop-variable-scope))