# Why do parentheses of for loop create a local scope?

Tags: javascript

Let's create a simple `for` loop.

```
for(let i = 0; ; ){ 
  console.log(i);
}
```

What I noticed that `i` is assumed as local to `for` statement. Even if it was not declared inside `{}`.

As I got used to that the local scope for `let` variable is created by curly braces: `if`, `do...while`, `while`.

Does JavaScript have more examples like this when local scope is created by parentheses?

Comment: Because that's how the language defines what `let` does in a `for` loop.

Comment: The declaration of `i` is within the `for` statement.

Comment: Andrew, so does statement define a scope in JS? I thought that scope is defined by curly braces.

Comment: It's kind-of a weird wrinkle in the way the language works. There are really *two* scopes involved: the scope of the `for` loop header, and the scope of the loop body. It's invisible to the programmer, and it behaves as if it's the same `i` in the header and the body.

Comment: Pointy, finally! Thanks a lot. Can you please provide a link with a detailed description of this interesting behavior?

Comment: @KirillDevope MDN web docs explains it: [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: @andrew-morton it doesn't.

Comment: @KirillDevope You could read the ECMAScript Language Specification linked to on the page I linked to, depending on what you consider to suffice for a description. `var` was too loose and let variables leak out all over the place, so `let` was added to keep them to a scope.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main difference between `let` and `var` is that `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement:

```
{
  let a = 10;
}

console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

at the same time `var` would work fine with that scenario.

Getting back to your example, the same is happening with `for` loop.
So one of the solution, if you want to have an access to counter - is to create external variable and use it in your loop. You can also achieve the same result with `while`:

```
let counter = 0;

while(counter < 5) {
  // do stuff
  counter++;
} 

console.log(counter); // 5
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I looking for. I understand how local scope works inside curly braces. I just don't understand why variable declared inside `for()` not `{}` is assumed like a local variable of the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465211/javascript-loop-variable-scope

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is the type of variable you're saving the index value for. We have two solutions to solve this problem. First:

```js
let i = 0; /* using let out of for loop */
for(;i < 5; i++){
  console.log("for:" + i);
}

console.log(i); // no error
```

Second:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ /* Using var */
  console.log("for:" + i);
}

console.log(i); // no error
```

Comment: I think it's more that those are two ways to create a problem of the variable having more scope than needed in most cases ;)

Comment: Actually, the error is not a problem for me. I referred to the error here just to show that the scope of the ```i``` is "obviously" not global

Comment: Andrew, you're right. And if that create a problem. That can be solve with `delete i;`

Comment: Kirill, Thats become problem, beacause v8 engine thinks `i` part of loop and this cannot be global. I when tried run original code on nodejs i get : `for:0
for:1
for:2
for:3
for:4
for:0
for:1
for:2
for:3
for:4` in console. After that code gives error. Thats mean this code cause bug in nodejs.

Comment: I just don't understand why if you declare ```i``` inside of ```for()``` becomes declared in the local scope of loop.