# What is the temporal dead zone?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, let

I've heard that accessing `let` and `const` values before they are initialized can cause a `ReferenceError` because of something called the **temporal dead zone**.

What is the temporal dead zone, how does it relate to scope and hoisting, and in what situations is it encountered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572) - although the question doesn't focus on the TDZ, the answers are basically the same

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`let` and `const` have two broad differences from `var`:

1. They are [block scoped](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/).
2. Accessing a `var` before it is declared has the result `undefined`; accessing a `let` or `const` before it is declared throws `ReferenceError`:

```js
console.log(aVar); // undefined
console.log(aLet); // Causes ReferenceError: Cannot access 'aLet' before initialization

var aVar = 1;
let aLet = 2;
```

It appears from these examples that `let` declarations (and `const`, which works the same way) may not be [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), since `aLet` does not appear to exist before it is assigned a value.

That is not the case, however—`let` and `const` *are* hoisted (like `var`, `class` and `function`), but there is a period between entering scope and being declared where they cannot be accessed. **This period is the temporal dead zone (TDZ)**.

The TDZ ends when `aLet` is *declared*, rather than *assigned*:

```js
// console.log(aLet) // Would throw ReferenceError

let aLet;

console.log(aLet); // undefined
aLet = 10;
console.log(aLet); // 10
```

This example shows that `let` is hoisted:

```js
let x = "outer value";

(function() {
  // Start TDZ for x.
  console.log(x);
  let x = "inner value"; // Declaration ends TDZ for x.
}());
```

Credit: [Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ) demystified](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified).

Accessing `x` in the inner scope still causes a `ReferenceError`. If `let` were not hoisted, it would log `outer value`.

The TDZ is a good thing because it helps to highlight bugs—accessing a value before it has been declared is rarely intentional.

The TDZ also applies to default function arguments. Arguments are evaluated left to right, and each argument is in the TDZ until it is assigned:

```
// b is in TDZ until its value is assigned.
function testDefaults(a = b, b) { }

testDefaults(undefined, 1); // Throws ReferenceError because the evaluation of a reads b before it has been evaluated.
```

The TDZ is not enabled by default in the [babel.js](https://babeljs.io) transpiler. Turn on "high compliance" mode to use it in the [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl). Supply the `es6.spec.blockScoping` flag to use it with the CLI or as a library.

Recommended further reading: [TDZ demystified](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified) and [ES6 Let, Const and the “Temporal Dead Zone” (TDZ) in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-let-const-and-temporal-dead-zone-in-depth).

Comment: Also interesting: [Why is there a temporal dead zone](http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/why-tdz.html)

Comment: @zeroflagL good link, thanks.  Also it says: "foo is not undeclared, it is uninitialized", that language would be helpful to clarify/correct in the answer above.  `let foo` in a block causes it to be hoisted and declared at the top of that block.  The line of `let foo` causes it to be initialised.  And `foo = xyz` causes it to be assigned a value.

Comment: I think this is a great post! However, I was under the impression that 'let' was not subject to hoisting? I found this in the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let

I'm not trying to be a curmudgeon, I was just curious and am opened to clarification.

Comment: @dmarges the third code snippet shows that `let` is hoisted - otherwise the snippet would log `"outer value"`. Instead it throws a `ReferenceError` because `x` is the hoisted inner variable, which is in the TDZ.

Comment: It shows the opposite though. If let vars are hoisted, then the output would be "undefined". let vars are block scope, so the JS compiler would only really care about the let x in the IIFE since that would be a distinct block. Even then, it is throwing the ReferenceError because x variable is not in the variable table as far as the compiler is concerned. Replacing the let with var in the IIFE proves this because the output would be undefined.

Comment: Nope - both are hoisted (the `var`/`let`, but not any initial assignment are logically moved to the top of their function [or block for let - but it's a function here]), but before assignment `var`s are undefined and `let`s throw a `ReferenceError` because of the TDZ.

Comment: @jeows The MDN page still says they're not hoisted. You should try to edit that, if you are truly certain of what you are saying. I think I should post a question about that.

Comment: If it weren't for the behavior in the third example, everyone could say that they are not hoisted, and we would have one fewer intricate detail.

Comment: Without hoisting the third example would have the variable x referencing two different values in the same scope, which would be another intricate and very confusing detail.

Comment: @joews IMO, you could either say they are hoisted but they can't be accessed before their declaration is reached because of the TDZ, or you could say they are not hoisted but the TDZ will cause any references to them to throw an error. Practically, both statements are equally true. Except, I think, you are using the term "hoisting" in an abstract sense, as in "hoisting = whenever the engine is aware of that variable's existence". Is that why ? Plus, what do the specs say on that ?

Comment: Very clear and concise answer, I like this way better than any other answers here.

Answer (score 19):

**Hoisting:**
`let`,`const`,`var` are all get hoisted process.
(whats mean they go upper and declare in the top of the scope.)

**Initialisation:**

- `var` go also through the initial process, and get initial value of `undefined`.
- while `let`,`const` didn't go throw the initial process, so their values are still inaccessible, although they already declared.
  whats put them in `temporal dead zone`

**So in shortly:**

> hoisting process: `var`, `let`, `const`
>  Initialisation process:
>   `var`

Comment: I guess it's also important to mention that `let` and `const` are block scope, `var` is function scoped

Answer (score 10):

In case of let and const variables, Basically, Temporal Dead Zone is a zone

"before your variable is declared",

i.e where you can not access the value of these variables, it will throw an error.

ex.

```
let sum = a + 5;        //---------
//some other code       //         | ------>  this is TDZ for variable a
                        //         |
console.log(sum)        //---------
let a = 5;
```

above code gives an error

the same code will not give an error when we use var for variable 'a',

ex.

```
var sum = a;                            
console.log(sum)     //prints undefined
var a = 5;
```

Comment: the console log produces "NaN" in the second example ( the result of adding `undefined` and `5`). The _declaratation_ of `var a` is hoisted, the inifialisation code settng `a` to 5 is not.

Comment: yes, right, a is hoisted without any initialization. So a will be undefined.

Comment: The 1st example quoted is not right, please correct it or remove it.