# LET vs VAR and Hoisting from Block Scope to Global Scope

Tags: javascript, hoist

In light of questions:

[Understanding let vs. var hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021132/understanding-let-vs-var-hoisting) and

[Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6)

I do not understand what happens when hoisting lifts a variable out of block scope, into global scope.

In my code, I have:

```
<script>

    "use strict";

    let PageInit = null;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

        PageInit = new IPageInit();

        doSomething();

    });

    function doSomething() {
        alert(PageInit.RefreshCounter); // 60 //correct
    }

</script>
```

`PageInit` being created in the global scope is visible to `doSomething()`.

However, if I do this:

```
<script>

    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

        var PageInit = new IPageInit();

        doSomething();

    });

    function doSomething() {
        alert(PageInit.RefreshCounter); // referenceError
    }

</script>
```

I am not understanding hoisting properly.  I expected that `var PageInit` inside block scope would get hoisted into global scope, first thing inside the `<script>` tag.

But it doesn't.

Can anyone explain why not?  Or where does it get hoisted to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand what happens when hoisting lifts a variable out of block scope, into global scope.

This never happens.

Hosting affects **when** a variable comes into existence, not **where**.

> ```
> document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
>
>     PageInit = new IPageInit();
> ```

That implicitly declares a global. It isn't hosted. The variable doesn't exist until the function is run. Trying to read the variable before then will result in an exception.

> ```
> document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
>
>     var PageInit = new IPageInit();
> ```

`var` declares a variable in the scope of the function it is declared inside. So it **won't** create a global.

It **is** hoisted … but as it is the first line in the function, that makes no practical difference.

Comment: Ugh.  Totally embarassed.  I completely overlooked the fact that the body of my EventListener is a function.  That's even one of my own criticisms of fat arrow functions is that not actually having the keyword "function", you are more likely to overlook them AS functions, [ as opposed to using an anonymous function, ala, "function () {}" ].  which is exactly what I did here.  Still, this is the answer that is closest to what I was hoping to learn.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    var PageInit = new IPageInit();

    doSomething();

});
```

`var` has a functional scope. This means no matter where you declare a variable in a function, it's available to the entire function.

```js
function fn () {
  console.log(b)
  var b = 10
}

fn()

/* this is same as writing
function fn () {
  var b ======================> hoisted
  console.log(b)
   b = 10
}
*/
```

This doesn't mean that the variable declared inside a function would be available outside of it.
And this is why `PageInit` in `doSomething` function gives reference error. You will have to initialize the variable outside the function to not get this error

Answer (score 1):

**Scope in JavaScript**

Scope in JavaScript defines accessibility of variables, objects and functions.

There are two types of scope in JavaScript.

1. Global Scope
2. Local Scope

**Global Scope**

Variables declared outside of any function become global variables. Global variables can be accessed and modified from any function.

**Local Scope**

Variables declared inside any function with var keyword are called local variables. Local variables cannot be accessed or modified outside the function declaration.

We all know that `let` is block scope and `var` is it's current execution context .

**Conclusion**

In your first example `let` can be access because it's scope is global and he is in main block.
In your second example `var` is in it's local scope that's why it is unable to output it's value

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble figuring out what your intention is in the script. however and in any case ....

no, **var** is valid within its "*general purpose scope*" so "*in the tree of its functions and subfunctions*". So you don't find it because you are instancing a new situation and that var will be lost if not passed between the parameters.

If you use **let** it is even worse because *it is valid only within that function* and does not access the sub functions if not passed as a parameter.

In all this you are acting on an event system ... events are simil to ajax (create only on moment and lost out that event). it's difficult to process them by extracting data without saving them somewhere or pass it from function to another.

it is useful for understanding:
https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e

a more correct version would be like:

simple idea (I have not tested it but the logic is that)

```
var XXX;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", XXX => {

    XXX = new IPageInit();

    doSomething(XXX);

}, false); 

function doSomething(myval) {
    alert(myval); // now have XXX here 
}
```

So... xxx passed into success of event => and passed on doSomethig.

or...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    var XXX = getaval();

    doSomething(XXX);

}, false); 

function getaval() {
     return IPageInit(); // now have XXX here 
}

function doSomething(myval) {
    alert(myval); // now have XXX here 
}
```

So... on event => get or do what you have. if have nothing... get.

I hope I have been useful to you at least a little.