# Why is let much slower after a for loop than before a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, let

In node.js v6.0.0

```js
function testlet() {
 let a = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
}

function testlet2() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
 let a = 0;
}

console.time('let');
testlet();
console.timeEnd('let'); 

console.time('let2');
testlet2();
console.timeEnd('let2');
```

How can the position of `let` in the code cause such a big performance difference?

Comment: same effect in chrome (no surprises) - no such difference in other browsers

Comment: It also happens with `const`, but with `var` it's the same speed for both.

Comment: Strange as it is, I'd recommend not worrying too much about it. Micro-optimizations are a moving target. What's fast today can easily be slow tomorrow.

Comment: under the test : both node.js and chrome browser show different performance, firefox is the same and fast than V8. safari not support let

Comment: Can you please post which results you get?

Answer (score 7):

I'll take an educated guess and say that the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572) is the culprit.

That loop, which seems to be what your microbenchmark is about, is [eaten by the optimiser for breakfast](http://mrale.ph/talks/goto2015/#/71) as Vyacheslav Egorov [likes to put it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU&feature=player_detailpage#t=436) in his talks. And even it it isn't and the engine will increment a variable a million times, it will take the same time in both functions.

What is different is when the variable `a` is created. In your first snippet, it's at the beginning at the function, there is nothing before it. There is no temporal dead zone, it's essentially a function-scope variable; changing it to a `var` would not make a difference (try it). So when the function is invoked, the scope with the variable is created and the value is intialised to `0`, then some code runs (or not).
In contrast, in the second snippet there is a temporal dead zone. In the code preceding the `let` declaration, accessing `a` must throw an exception. So when the function is invoked, the scope is created and a slot for `a` is reserved but left uninitialised. In this state, the code is run (or not), and only after that the variable will get initialised and assigned with the value `0`.

So if the `let` is in the midst of the code (or after it), scoping is more complex. This might cause the optimiser to treat it differently, maybe even affect the variable `i` which is in the same scope, or possibly not being able to do certain optimisations at all.