# What happens to the function parameters in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the code:

```
function stuff() {
    console.log('stuffing');
}

stuff = stuff;

stuffy = () => stuff();

stuffx = () => console.log('tobi');
function stuffers(stuff = stuffx) {
    stuff();
    stuffy();
}

stuffers();
```

The result is what one would expect:

```
tobi
stuffing
```

But when changing the *stuffers* function signature like this:

```
function stuff() {
    console.log('stuffing');
}

stuff = stuff;

stuffy = () => stuff();

stuffx = () => console.log('tobi');
function stuffers(stuff = stuff) {
    stuff();
    stuffy();
}

stuffers();
```

The result is:

```
ReferenceError: stuff is not defined
```

**Why is this happening ONLY in the case of having the same name?**

Comment: stuff = stuff? what you want to achieve..?

Comment: Why are you doing `stuff = stuff;`? stuff is already a function object above

Comment: Because `stuff` in the context of the `stuffers` function is a local variable (not the main `stuff` function first declared). YOu then assign it (the null one) to itself (effectively this is not doing anything), so thats why you get undefined. Basically, the new local `stuff` takes priority over the `stuff` function

Comment: [Sort of related/duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722854/default-parameters-in-es6-throws-error), but with only one parameter here.

Comment: "Because stuff in the context of the stuffers function is a local variable (not the main stuff function first declared). YOu then assign it (the null one) to itself". But then why does the first version work, it also accesses the globally defined functions. If you would use stuffx = stuff it would also work, only when it has the same name as a globally defined function does it result in undefined. I wanted to understand why is it happening ONLY for the case of having the same name.

Comment: @RandomCatGamer please check the babel link I provided. My answer was downvoted but I don't know why. If you see why, please let me know :)

Comment: @RandomCatGamer: Because when you use the same name, the new local variable (`stuff`) takes priority, basically, it becomes the only `stuff` that the function knows about. It cannot reference the original  `stuff` function. It works in the other examples, because there is no conflict. `stuffx = stuff` works because `stuffx` is the new local variable, and it is assigned with reference to the `stuff` function, which it can see correctly because there is no conflict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in Your case you're ovverriding the globally defined stuff function with it's local declaration.
As xadhix mentioned, this declaration

```
function stuffers(stuff = stuff) {
    stuff();
    stuffy();
}
```

Compiles down to (i've split it to 3 parts to provide readable comments):

```
function stuffers() {
    var stuff;
```

Above the globally defined stuff is redeclared in local context.

```
    stuff = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : stuff;
```

Here happens the default assigment from function declaration (stuff = stuff) , but the variable has already been reinitialized in this scope with undefined value, so it is simply assigning an undefined value again to the stuff variable (stuff = stuff)

```
    stuff(); //error
    stuffy();
}
```

This does not happen in "working" example as stuffx is not present in the local scope and the assigment stuff = stuffx does not produce undefined value.

The full snippet of what is actually executed from stuffers perspective is

```
function stuffers() {
    var stuff;
    stuff();
    stuffy();
}
```