# Why does console.log(z) throw NaN?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When it's able to pick up `w` from the outer scope, why is it not able to pick up `z`?

```js
var w = 1, z = 2;
function foo( x = w + 1, y = x + 1, z = z + 1 ) {
 console.log( x, y, z );
}
foo();
```

Comment: It doesn't "throw" anything.

Comment: http://www.es6fiddle.net/itodgq1r/

Comment: I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: z is not defined'.

Can you initialize vars like that is js?

Comment: @Shane you don't need a fiddle, you can run the code directly here.

Comment: @OrangeDog It should in any proper ES6 environment. `z` (which is a local variable because of the parameter name) is still uninitialised - just like in `let z = z + 1`. The global variable is shadowed.

Comment: @Bergi oh, then maybe a fiddle is required...

Comment: @Bergi this question is not about TDZ, it's about variable shadowing. You should either reopen this answer or use another question as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the referenced one.

Comment: @mdziekon it's about both. You're right, I better reopen and answer

Comment: Somehow it doesn't get an error when you use `c = z + 1` instead of `z = z + 1`, why this happens? I guess its confusing an instanced variable z with the global variable z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's able to pick up `w` from the outer scope

Yes, because you don't have a variable `w` inside your function.

> why is it not able to pick up `z`?

Because your parameter declares a local variable with the name `z`, and that shadows the global one. However, the local one is not yet initialised with a value inside the default expression, and throws a `ReferenceError` on accessing it. It's like the [temporal dead zone for `let`/`const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572),

```
let z = z + 1;
```

would throw as well. You should rename your variable to something else to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The first one works because the `w` in the `w + 1` looks for w in the formal parameters but does not find it and the outer scope is used. Next, The `x` in the `x +1` finds the value for x in formal parameters scope and uses it, so the assignment to y works fine.

In the last case of `z + 1`, it finds the `z` as not yet initialized in the formal parameter scope and throws an error before even trying to find it from outer scope.

Changing the variable z to something else as pointed out by @bergi, should do the trick.

```
var w = 1, z = 2;
function foo( x = w + 1, y = x + 1, a = z + 1 ) {
 console.log( x, y, a );
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have
`function foo( x = w + 1, y = x + 1, z = z + 1 )`

during 
`x=w+1`
`x` is undfined 
and then `w` is undefined also 
so it look into local execution context didnt find any value 
so it goes outerscope and find w=1 
so in local space `w` also become 1

now during 
`z = z + 1`
the `z` which is at the left side of `=` is undefine 
and then the `z` which is at the right side of `=` also undifine so it looks for 
z inside local execution context and find one the `z` which was at the left side 
of the equation so it do not need to go to outer space.
so `z` become undifine

however if you write this way `z=this.z+1` you will get z= 3 
cause `this.z` wont look into localscope directly go to outerscope and find z=2