# Why does a `let` assignment that uses the same variable name in its right-hand side throw a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, variables

I’m sure it’s a little caveat somewhere but, here is the issue:

```js
var x = x || {}; // Works!
let y = y || {}; // ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'y' before initialization
const z = z || {}; // ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'z' before initialization
```

The `let` and `const` cases throw *“ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration* 'variableName' *before initialization”*.

What is going on here? I can kind of understand the `const` one, but how is `let` not working either?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? How do you expect even the `var` code to work?

Comment: I don't think any of them would work ?
however var might work because of hoisting ..

Answer (score 1):

1. Variables declared with `var` are hoisted to the top of the enclosing function or global scope. They are assigned the initial value of `undefined`. Hence the example line of code `var x = x || {};` is transformed by hoisting and default value initialization into this equivalent code:

   ```
   var x = undefined;
   x = x || {};
   ```

   Because `x` already has a value when the right-hand side of the assignment statement is evaluated, the code proceeds normally.

   Side note: You can declare a variable with `var` even after the first assignment (due to top-hoisting), and declaring more than once is idempotent (e.g. `var x; var x;`).
2. Variables declared with `let` and `const` are hoisted to the top of the enclosing block, but are not given a default value. If such a variable is read before a value is assigned, a `ReferenceError` is thrown. Your example line of code is transformed by hoisting into this equivalent code:

   ```
   let y;
   y = y || {};
   ```

   To execute the assignment statement, the right side is first evaluated, then its value is assigned to the variable on the left side. But in this case, the right side reads `y`, which has not been assigned a value yet — hence an error is thrown.

   Everything that is in the same scope as the `let` statement, but executed earlier (i.e. above `let` or the right-hand side of a `let` assignment) is within the [Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849).

---

Note that in JavaScript, a piece of code like `let x = x + 1;` throws an exception only if execution reaches that statement. Whereas in other languages like Java, the same piece of code is always a compile-time error, even if it’s buried inside an `if(false){...}`. This emphasizes the behavior of variable hosting, and the fact that JavaScript examines what the code means when it is executed, hence these examples are not syntax errors in a strict sense.

Comment: [`let` and `const` are hoisted as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572), the only difference is that they are not initialised with the default value `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much. Fixing now...