# How to fix "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'io' before initialization" in socket.io client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hi i am trying to create a basic realtime application in socket.io , i have completely setup the server side in node.js and the file "socket.io.js" is also being imported in browser but somehow when i try to connect with socket.io server using `let io = io()` or `let io = io.connect()` i get the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'io' before initialization
```

node.js code:

[image]

client code:

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why does a `let` assignment that uses the same variable name in its right-hand side throw a ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42967145/4642212). Can’t vote-to-close this one because the answer is at score 0.

Comment: Thank you , it worked by changing let to var

Comment: A better way would be to simply use a different variable name, like `connectedIO`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a \`let\` assignment that uses the same variable name in its right-hand side throw a ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967145/why-does-a-let-assignment-that-uses-the-same-variable-name-in-its-right-hand-s)

Answer (score 0):

After reading a comment on this post i fixed the issue by changing the let with var keyword.