# Declaring variable with LET/ECMAscript 6 if it doesn't already exist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This works great:

```
var x = x || 3 //x = 3
```

This does not:

```
let y = y || 4 //Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

My IDE ([[image]webstorm](/questions/tagged/webstorm)) warns me on all usages of `var`, so I've been trying to avoid it (I assume this is current best practice).  So what is the correct way to instantiate a variable only if it doesn't already exist?

---

**Use Case**: I am dynamically loading "widgets", which include an HTML, Javascript and CSS file.  Each Javascript file has its own closure (`widget = (function() {})()`).  I need to be able to "reload" these.

Comment: `var` allows redefining variable names while `let` does not. You can statically analyze whether a name exists within scope. If the `y` name is defined in scope, you'd do `y = y || 4` with no let prefix. If `y` is not defined in scope, you'd just do `let y = 4`.

Comment: If this is within a function and you're passing `y` in you can set `y` as a default. [Might be a good way around that specific case.](https://jsfiddle.net/zshht4Lm/1/)

Comment: [The right-hand side `y` is in a temporal dead zone no matter the outer context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone) I'd also consider `var x = x || 3;` immoral, even if it is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `y` first, then set its value in a different statement.

```
let y;
y = y || 4;
```

You can't declare with `let` or `const` multiple times, so you'll do that `let` declaration somewhere at the top of the scope you want it in.

Comment: This does not help. It causes `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'nearby' has already been declared` on reload

Comment: @RatherNotsay It does, refresh the answer, I just added a clarifying statement.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Basically, separate the declaration from the setting of its value.  You can only declare it once, but you can set its value as much as you want.

Comment: I added a use case to the question. If this is my only option, I'll have to rethink how I'm doing some things...

Comment: @RatherNotsay Looking at your use case, I don't see what the problem is.  You can declare your widget variables up top with `let`.  Then load them on the fly later.  If you have a dynamic set of widgets, you might just use something like `const widgets = {}`, and then to load a widget, `widgets[widgetName] = widgets[widgetName] || loadWidget(widgetName)`.

Comment: @RatherNotsay There are also existing loaders for things like this which you might look into.

Comment: To declare them "up top" I would need to know ahead of time what each widget would be named and which ones would be loaded, which sort of defeats the purpose of loading them dynamically.