# Scope in ES6 confusion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let cards = ['Diamond', 'Spade', 'Heart', 'Club'];

let currentCard = 'Heart';

while (currentCard !== 'Spade') {
  console.log(currentCard);
  let currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() *4)];
}

console.log(currentCard);
```

Here my concern is about the error that currentCard is not defined , even though I have declared it globally.

So I am thinking that the error message `currentCard is not defined` should not come.

Comment: Remove let in while loop

Comment: why one should remove let ,what is the problem in it??

Comment: @alex you're redeclaring `currentCard` in that scope

Comment: @FedericoThat thing I understand but what is the relation of the error which it is giving that currentCard is not defined with the above said logic

Comment: I think output should come as Heart

Comment: You didn't say where the error is fired, is it inside the `while`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have defined your variable with `let` in both your your global scope AND in your `while` loop. `let` is scoped by a block scope, so inside your while loop is a different one than in your global scope.

It is crashing on line 6, the `console.log` just below the while definition. You define your variable inside the while loop in the line below your `console.log`. Therefore Javascript does not find your variable because it is not defined yet.

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

> Variables declared by let have as their scope the block in which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks. In this way, let works very much like var. The main difference is that the scope of a var variable is the entire enclosing function

Comment: I understand,here I have written console.log(currentCard) outside the while loop so it should refer the global scope variable that is  let currentCard = 'Heart';

Comment: It is crashing on line 6, the console.log just below the while definition. You define your variable inside the while loop in the line below. Therefore Javascript does not find your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining currentCard in the while loop. Remove the extra let and it should work.

Comment: why it should work??.....

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the `while` block's `console` statement.

> So I am thinking that the error message currentCard is not defined
>   should not come.

**No**, even though you have declared `currentCard` globally, you have re-declared it in the `while` loop block and **accessed it before you have initialized the same**.

Read more about [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone).