# Is it a bad practice to use await inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, async-await

Is it a bad practice to use a await inside a while loop?

I have the following code:

```
// this is inside a async function
try {
  let res = await api.resource.create(...args) // create resource
  do {
    let res = await api.resource.show(res.body.id)
    if (res.body.status === 'COMPLETED')
      return res.body
  } while(1)
} catch (err) {
  errorHandler(err)
}
```

I have a couple of questions here:

1. Is it ok to use two res variables?
2. Am I going to use performance because I'm using a await inside a while loop?
3. Is there a better solutin?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Key question to answer: why are you using a while loop here?

Comment: Hmm kind off.. This basically renders the benefit of using a async method completely useless, since you could just synchronously do this. Also what is the purpose of having a variable `res` in the try block and in the while loop.

Comment: For 1, it makes your code less readable. For 2, compared to what alternative? For 3, depends on 2, but you might want to add a timeout to not overkill your server (if `api.resource.show()` indeed includes a call to a server). Otherwise, in a general sense, await in while loop is just fine.

Comment: @Kaiido In fact the timeout is not needed IF `api.resource.show()` includes some sort of async call, since the await will stop execution until the returned Promise resolves ;)

Comment: @Bellian if `api.resource.show()` consists only of `fetch(server.url)` and the response is just "in progress" you will stress your server out by making thousands requests per minute. Add a bunch of users doing it simultaneously and you've just DDoS your own server with your own bad js. Also, the main goal of syntactic sugar `async/await` is actually to make loops easier to manage, since even with Promises, that was an hell to manage. Probably since OP is awaiting for `show()`, it is an asynchronous call, which makes the use of async/await very on purpose,contrarily to what your comment states

Comment: Just saying, `let res = …(res.body.id)` in a block scope will always throw a `ReferenceError` because of the temporal dead zone. Drop the `let`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Am I going to use performance*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it ok to use two `res` variables?

No. The way you are using the inner one, the access in the arguments is always in the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572) and you will always get an exception.

> Am I going to use performance because I'm using a `await` inside a while loop?

There's nothing wrong with using `await` in loops, as long as you expect them to run sequentially and not all iterations concurrently.

> Is there a better solution?

```
try {
  let res = await api.resource.create(...args) // create resource
  do {
    res = await api.resource.show(res.body.id)
  } while (res.body.status !== 'COMPLETED')
  return res.body
} catch (err) {
  errorHandler(err)
}
```

Notice also that if `errorHandler` comes from a callback parameter, you should drop the entire `try`/`catch` and just use `.catch(errorHandler)` on the promise returned by the call.

Also, while I don't know what `api.resource.show` does, it looks like you are polling for a result. It would be better if the method would just return a promise that fulfills at the right time. If that is not possible and you need to poll, I would recommend at least some delay between the calls.

Comment: Hi @merge, your aswer really cleared my mind. What do you recommend to do to delay the calls?

Comment: Just `await delay(500);` in the loop, with a `delay` function that wraps `setTimeout` in a promise.