# JavaScript variable hoisting behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm probably missing something very fundamental but I would like to ask this regardless

```
var a=100;
function f(){
    console.log(a)
    const a=150
}
console.log(a)
f();
```

Prints 100 and throws an error while changing const a=150 to var a=150 returns 100 and undefined. I'm unsure why this behavior occurs and any pointers to relevant info is appreciated

Comment: You should remove the 'Const' from your code. You can just say a=150, after a variable is declared

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-hoisting-dfa84512dd28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this is how hoisting works:

- the declaration of the variable is moved to the top
- the variable is initialized with a special "hoisted" value
- when the program reaches the `var/let/const` line, the variable is re-initialized with the value mentioned on that line (or `undefined` if there's none).

Now, your example can be simplified down to this:

```js
console.log(a)
let a = 150
```

which is actually:

```
a = <hoisted value>
console.log(a)
a = 150
```

It throws an error because, for `let` and `const`, the hoisted value is a special object that raises an error when you try to access it.

On the other side, the hoisted value for `var` is just `undefined`, so this will print `undefined` without throwing an error:

```js
console.log(a)
var a = 150
```

Also, there's some confusion (including this very thread) about which variable types are hoisted, and a so-called "dead zone" for `let/const` vars. It's simpler to think of things this way: **everything is hoisted**, that is, all variable bindings in a block are created before entering the block. The only difference between `var` and `let/const` in this regard is that with the latter you are not allowed to use a binding until you initialize it with a value.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/989121 for more details.

Comment: Might mention the TDZ for further reading on that.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I personally find the notion of TDZ quite confusing and deliberately tried to explain things without resorting to it.

Comment: This was very clear and easy to understand. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

`const` and `let` have temporal dead zone so when you try to access `const` or `let` before it is instantiated you get an error.

This is not true for `var`. `var` is hoisted at the top meaning it is instantiated with a value of `undefined` just before a function code is run.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with new ES6, let and const, hoisting is not applied what this means is that a variable declared with either let or const cannot be accessed until after the declaration, if you do this will throw and error

```
 var a=100;
    function f(){


        console.log(a)// throws an error because is accessed before is declared....
        const a=150
    }
    console.log(a)
    f();
```

This is commonly called [the Temporal Dead Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)

On the other hand using Var will apply hoisting what this does is defines the variable in memory before all the scope is executed...

```
 var a=100;
    function f(){


        console.log(a)// This won't throw an error
        var a=150
    }
    console.log(a)
    f();
```

Comment: Not really, hoisting _is_ applied to let vars, otherwise the log line would print the global `a`.

Comment: You can try it, using let, this will throw an error the same way as using const..

Comment: Thanks, I will try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

the variable with const cannot be declared more then once,

and when you declares `const a=150` inside a function, it deleted the previous variable and this is why the error is coming

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer your looking for is `const` is block scope and is not hoisted, whereas `var` is hoisted.

That's why you get 100, "Error: a is not defined" with:

```
var a=100;
function f(){
    console.log(a)
    const a=150
}
console.log(a)
f();
```

and 100, undefined with:

```
var a=100;
function f(){
    console.log(a)
    var a=150
}
console.log(a)
f();
```

In the second instance a is declared, but it is not defined yet. You'll see the same result with:

```
function f() {
    console.log(a)
    var a=150
}
console.log(a)
f();
```

Since the var inside the function is hoisted.

Bottom line: `const` variables are not hoisted, `var` variables are.