# Declaring variable with same name as lexical scope results ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I am sure the question title is complicated but my problem is a little bit tough. I will also try to be instructive in this question.

I am working on a new blog post about hoisting but I am stuck with a question.

Lets first give an example of hoisting.

```
function logCar() {
  console.log('Car: ' + carName);
}
logCar();
var carName = 'Yoyota';
```

So we expect a log without an error: `Car: undefined`. Behind the scene, it is being converted to the code below.

```
var carName;
function logCar(){
   console.log('Car: ' + carName)
}
logCar();
carName = 'Yoyota';
```

So it is working without an exception. Let's try using `let` which is not hoisted.

```
function logCar() {
  console.log('Car: ' + carName);
}
logCar();
let carName = 'Yoyota';
```

This code immediately throws a `ReferenceError: carName is not defined`. So I can clearly understand that **let is not hoisted**. `let carName;` is not being moved to the top of block scope.

Then I wanted to use parent scope as a lexical scope of `logCar` and it works perfectly and outputs `Yoyota` without an error.

```
let car = 'Yoyota';
const logCar = () => {
  console.log(car);
}
logCar();
```

As I am using let I can also change the car name for my `logCar` scope without affecting parent.

```
let car = 'Yoyota';
const logCar = () => {
  let car = 'MWB';
  console.log(car);
}
logCar();
console.log(car);
```

It outputs exactly what I am expecting. First 'MWB', then 'Yoyota'. Then, I wanted to redeclare `variable` car in `logCar` scope but before declaring it I wanted to use the `variable` from lexical scope.

```
let car = 'Yoyota';
const logCar = () => {
  console.log(car); // ReferenceError: car is not defined
  let car = 'MWB';
  console.log(car);
}
logCar();
```

Then I got a `ReferenceError: car is not defined` error. But why? `car` should be defined on the lexical scope as it works on the previous example? Why adding `let car = 'MWB'` to that scope makes it throw error while let is not being hoisted?

Comment: `let` declarations *are* hoisted, to the top off the enclosing block, but unlike `var` it's an error to refer to the variable between the top of the block and the point of (apparent) declaration. It's called ["the temporal dead zone".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)