# Hoisting inside Function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain below code:

What will be the value of myVar inside function b?

```
function a() {
        function b() {
            console.log("b", myVar); 
        }
        b();
    let myVar;    
    console.log("a", myVar);  //Look for a execution context
}
a();
```

Comment: It never gets initialized - it never gets a value, and is accessed before initialization, so it throws.

Comment: `let` is different to `var` - see the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone) - which is not a Stephen King short story

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Isn't the myVar should be hoisted to the top inside function "a" and as b function is sitting lexically inside "a" function it should look to its upper scope(i.e parent "a")

Answer (score 0):

**let** variables are not initialized until their definition is evaluated.
Accessing the variable before the initialization results in a ReferenceError

Comment: Isn't the myVar should be hoisted to the top inside function "a" and as "b" is sitting lexically inside "a" function it should look to its upper scope(i.e parent "a")

Comment: no, myVar are hoisted but period between entering scope and being declared where they cannot be accessed. This period is the temporal dead zone (TDZ). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone

Answer (score 0):

Declare myVar to var instead fo let.
it will give you undefined.
So it is a simple concept of Keyword let not concept of Hoisting inside a function.
Run only the below code. you will get the same error.

```
console.log(number); //Reference error
let number= 1;
```