# ArrowFunction in JavaScript in not working as expected, why? but the normal function is working fine

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-functions

Here, is the simple code where i'm trying to change the background color once I clicked on the button

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('.colorBtn');
const bodyBcg = document.querySelector('body');
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);

    // const changeColor = () => {
    //     let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    //     bodyBcg.style.background = colors[random];
    // };

function changeColor() {
    console.log('color change event');
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    bodyBcg.style.background = colors[random];
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.colorBtn {
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    border: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Hex Colors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="colorBtn">Click here to change color</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when we try with the Arrow Function named changeColor, it's not working:
Not able to understand the concept behind this.

```
const changeColor = () => {
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
bodyBcg.style.background = colors[random];
};
```

As well, It works fine in the chrome browser, but when I tried to put debug point on the working changeColor function, 
It throws error:

```
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('.colorBtn');
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: Uh, if you have the *exact* same code but just replace `function changeColor` with `const changeColor`, you are running into [a temporal deadzone problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone). Is that your issue or something else?

Comment: What error do you get when using an arrow function? Probably the issue is that you're trying to use the function before you define it, whereas a `function` declaration is *hoisted*…?

Comment: Great! Learned new concept of "hoisted"
With using of ArrowFunction I should take care of this! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because your `changeColor` variable is `undefined` when you want to link its function to the event listener.

Just define it before attaching your event listener.

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('.colorBtn');
const bodyBcg = document.querySelector('body');
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];

const changeColor = () => {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  bodyBcg.style.background = colors[random];
};

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.colorBtn {
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    border: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="colorBtn">Click here to change color</button>
```

---

*As a side note: in this case, `changeColor` is a **variable** containing an **anonymous function**.*

Please, look at [@Duc Hong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439672/5878071) for an explanation about *hoisting*.

Answer (score 1):

what you're running into is called `hoisting`. JavaScript uses two main methods for defining a function: Function declarations (sometimes referred to as function statements) and function expressions.

Function Declaration:

```
function fncName() {}
```

Function Expression:

```
const x = function fncName(){}
```

The main functional difference between these two methods is that function declarations are hoisted, meaning you can invoke the function even before it has been defined. Function expressions are not hoisted.

In your case, the arrow function is Function Expression, so:

```
const x = () => {}
```

is identical to:

```
const x = function fncName(){}
```

As much as I understand, arrow functions is used for 2 reasons: `minimal syntax` and `lexical this` .

Please take notice of this from [Arrow functions on Mozzila site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the **this**, **arguments**, **super**, or **new.target** keywords.