# Why function expressions are hoisted if called inside express js middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

We know that function declaration are hoisted and you can call them from anywhere in your script. That is not the case for function expressions.

For example:

```
 test();

 const test = () => {
    console.log(1+3);
 }

 When we call test() it will always return undefined.
```

But this does not happen when we call the same function inside expressjs middleware.

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   test(); // it will return always the result 4
})

const test = () => {
   console.log(1+3);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: The module code runs when the module is included, so at the time the `router.get` callback runs, `const test` is already in memory. This works in the browser, too: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n724ezvL/

Comment: That `test` call in the second snippet isn’t in the same scope as `const test` at all. Also, `const` and `let` declarations aren’t hoisted anyway. `test(); const test = () => {};` results in a [TDZ error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/4642212).

Comment: [`let` and `const` are hoisted as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572), just without their value initialsation. And the `get` callback isn't called immediately, but after the variable was initialised.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it has nothing to do with viarable types in this case

Comment: @AstritSpanca Yes, it has nothing to do with variable types. I didn’t say anything about variable types.

Answer (score 5):

Your first snippet, when run exactly as you show it, generates this error:

```
ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

Your second code snippet works because the module is initialized and `const test` is defined.  Then some time later, the route callback gets called and `test` is now defined and has a value in the module scope.

For `let` and `const`, it is an error to reference them in running code before they are initialized.  That's why the first code snippet generates a `ReferenceError`.

But, once initialized, they are available anywhere within the scope in which they are defined.  Some people call this hoisting to the top of the scope.  Because this works differently than `var` hoisting, I just think of it as once the `const` or `let` symbol is defined, it's available anywhere within its scope, even in code that might get called later, but appears earlier in the file.  This is consistent with Javascript's run-time lookup for variables.  When executing the route handler in your second code snippet, the symbol `test` is looked up dynamically within its scope.  Since `const test` has already run and been initialized by the time the route handler gets called, it finds an already initialized `test` variable and `test()` works just fine.

In your first code snippet, the dynamic lookup for `test` fails because `const test` has not yet run when you try to call `test()` and that creates the `ReferenceError`.

---

You can see a demonstration of that a little more simply in this code which is pretty much the same as your second snippet:

```
function a() {
    test();
}

const test = () => {
    console.log(1+3);
}

a();
```

Here, we define function `a` and then define `const test` as a function.  Then, we call `a()` which in turn calls `test()`.  Since the sequence of events was:

1. Define function a
2. Define const test as a function
3. Call `a()`
4. Which then calls `test()`

And, all symbols are accessible from the module scope, then you can see that `test` is defined before it is called so the code works.