# Javascript let hoisting behaviour question

Tags: javascript, hoisting

So I'm trying to run these 2 functions in chrome:

```
function let_test1() {
    debugger;
    let something = true;
    return something;
}

function let_test2() {
    debugger;
    console.log(something);
    let something = true;
    return something;
}
```

If in `let_test1` I try to evaluate `something` at the breakpoint, I get `undefined`.

If I try this in `let_test2` , I get a ReferenceError.

Any ideas why this happens?

**CLARIFICATION**

Not sure this is related directly to the TDZ answers since this pertains specifically to the first example resolving to 'undefined' instead of a 'Reference Error' and the question is what causes it. The TDZ in my understanding addresses the 'Reference Error' only.

Should so, why does it resolve to 'undefined' in the first example? As in my current understanding it should throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar `let` _is_ in fact hoisted

Comment: How ? any example can you provide

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar it's in the duplicate answer, the second block of code from the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198850/5648954