# Javascript: Does it matter where 'let' variables are initialized inside a block?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, initialization

The following behavior of Javascript is a complete mystery to me. The following code snippet does not work:

```
let someFunctionOne = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(1), 1000)))
let someFunctionTwo = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(2), 1000)))
let someFunctionThree = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(3), 1000)))

let myFunction = async () => {
    let resultOne
    if (true) {
        let resultTwo, resultThree // <-- doesn't work
        if (false) {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong')
        }

        const promiseOne = someFunctionOne()
        const promiseTwo = someFunctionTwo()
        const promiseThree = someFunctionThree()

        [resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree] = await Promise.all([
            promiseOne,
            promiseTwo,
            promiseThree]
        )
    resultOne = {resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree}
    }
    return resultOne
}
let result = await myFunction()
console.log(result)
```

This throws the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'promiseThree' before initialization
```

However, when the initialization of the two variables is put right above the Promise.all() call it does work:

```
    let someFunctionOne = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(1), 1000)))
let someFunctionTwo = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(2), 1000)))
let someFunctionThree = async () => (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(3), 1000)))

let myFunction = async () => {
    let resultOne
    if (true) {
        if (false) {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong')
        }

        const promiseOne = someFunctionOne()
        const promiseTwo = someFunctionTwo()
        const promiseThree = someFunctionThree()

        let resultTwo, resultThree // <-- does work

        [resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree] = await Promise.all([
            promiseOne,
            promiseTwo,
            promiseThree]
        )
    resultOne = {resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree}
    }
    return resultOne
}
let result = await myFunction()
console.log(result)
```

Why on earth is the second code snippet working and the first one isn't? For both, the variable initialization of resultTwo and resultThree happen before they are used...

Thanks

Comment: "_Does it matter where 'let' variables are initialized inside a block?_" [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone). But [I can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/tLgwue1v/) the error you claim with the first code. Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: @Ivar See my updated answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your issue isn't the spot where you put the `let`. It's the fact that you don't have a semicolon after the function call before that statement. See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). It is generally recommended to use semicolons, even though they are not always required by JavaScript.

Comment: @Ivar After which function call? Where exactly should the semicolon go in the first code snippet to make it work?

Comment: After `const promiseThree = someFunctionThree()`. Otherwise it will see the `[resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree]` as a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: @Ivar Wow that blew my mind. I was actually told that semicolons are completely optional for javascript nowadays... I guess that's not true. Thank you so much for your help