# ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration`X' before initialization

Tags: javascript, variables, let, hoisting

Can someone explain me the weird error messages that occur both in `chrome and firefox` when trying to access a `variable before the let declaration: "let X"`. if we write something like:

```js
console.log(X);
let X;

/*
In firefox it reports an error like:

ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'X' before initialization


In chrome it reports and error like:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'X' before initialization

*/
```

why it returns an error message like you saw in the above code without giving an error message like the below ones:

```js
console.log(X);
/* the error message i was expecting:

firefox: ReferenceError: X is not defined

chrome: ReferenceError: X is not defined


*/
```

does that mean `let` variables `hoist` too because the error messages show attributes of `let variables` being hoisted means that the javaScript engine knows when we try to access a `let variable` before it's declared

```
console.log(X);
let X;
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'X' before initialization
```

and please if you find any thing related to this behavior in [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) lemme know

Comment: Why wouldn't it hoist?  It's a variable just like a var.  It just has a reduced scope

Comment: so then why people call that `let variables` never `hoist`

Comment: What they mean is that you cannot use them before defined. As you see: Trying to do so throws an error.

Comment: However, an annoying side effect is of course that while they exist in their unassigned form, they can still shadow variables from outer scopes. So adding a `let location` in the last line of your function can still break your whole function's previous code, but at least it will do so in a more meaningful way. If you'd put `var location` into the last line of your function and your first line would have done `location = 'http://yahoo.com'`, then it would have _silently_ broken the code, but with `let` it does so in a noticable way.

Comment: I realize there is actually a better answer already on SO: [What is the temporal dead zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they "hoist" but as unaccessible thing which always throws an error when read or written. It's called the "temporal dead zone".

Further reading: https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/advanced-javascript-es6-temporal-dead-zone-default-parameters-and-let-vs-var-deep-dive-ca588fcde21b

> Conceptually, for example, a strict definition of hoisting suggests that variable and function declarations are physically moved to the top of your code, but this is not in fact what happens. Instead, the variable and function declarations are put into memory during the compile phase, but stay exactly where you typed them in your code. [Hositing]
>
> [...]
>
> For most of the ES6 features (let, const, default parameters, etc), The Creation Phase work quite differently. It still goes through the code and allocates space for variables, but the initializer set the variables with a special mode called TDZ (Temporal Dead Zone), which means the variables exist but you can’t access them until you assign some value.

So you can imagine it like this:

```js
let X = TDZ;
console.log(X); // error
X = undefined; // in your code: let X;
```

...compared to normal hosting behavior:

```js
var X = undefined;
console.log(X); // undefined
X = whatever; // in your code: var X = whatever;
```

Of course this is not 100% right because you also can't write `X = 123` before the `let`, and there is no valid JS that would describe an "unwritable variable". But I think you get the idea.

---

In the [ECMAScript 2021 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) this is described in 13.3.1 as follows (it seems it doesn't use the term "TDZ" there, although I have heard this name used many timed before, it's also used in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)):

> 13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations
>
> NOTE
>
> let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment. The variables are created when their containing Environment Record is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated. A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated.

This means that at the start of your block, the Environment Record is instantiated - the variable "exists" but is in the TDZ. As said here, it cannot be accessed, hence the error. Once the `let` line is executed, its LexicalBinding is evaluated and the variable comes out of the TDZ and is now accessible. Since you didn't specify an initializer, its value is now `undefined`.

Comment: is this mentioned in https://tc39.es/ecma262/ ECMAscript specs by the way thanks you saved me

Comment: Added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much