Issue while assigning CSS variable value to Javascript
In my website, I've a sticky container with a horizontal scroll direction.
The scroll works perfectly. However the issue is, when I tried to get a value from a CSS variable and assign it to Javascript I get this following error:

ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'paddingRight' before initialization



const spaceHolder = document.querySelector('.js-scroll-wrapper');
const horizontal = document.querySelector('.js-scroll-direction');

// Get existing CSS variable '--padding-right'
let el = document.querySelector('.c-scroll__content');
let gcs = getComputedStyle(el);
let paddingRight = gcs.getPropertyValue('--padding-right');

// alert('The value of the css variable is : ' + (paddingRight?paddingRight:'undefined'));

spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`; 

function calcDynamicHeight(ref) {
  const vw = window.innerWidth;
  const vh = window.innerHeight;
  const objectWidth = ref.scrollWidth;

  return objectWidth - vw + vh + paddingRight; // '--padding-right' CSS value of '.js-h-scroll-content'
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const sticky = document.querySelector('.js-scroll-sticky');
  horizontal.style.transform = `translateX(-${sticky.offsetTop}px)`;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;
});
body{
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.c-spacer{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100svh;
    clear: both;
}

.c-scroll{
    width: 100%;
}

.c-scroll__container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100svh;
}

.c-scroll__wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
    
.c-scroll__sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.c-scroll__horizontal{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
}

.c-scroll__content{
    --padding-right: 100;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 var(--padding-right);    
}

.c-scroll__item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

.c-scroll__item:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.c-scroll__item-title{
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.c-scroll__item-desc p{
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
<div class="c-spacer">Scroll</div>

<div class="c-scroll js-scroll">
  <div class="c-scroll__container">
    <div class="c-scroll__wrapper js-scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="c-scroll__sticky js-scroll-sticky">
        <div class="c-scroll__horizontal js-scroll-direction">
          <div role="feed" class="c-scroll__content js-scroll-content">
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 4</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 5</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 6</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 7</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 8</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 9</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c-scroll__item">
              <h2 class="c-scroll__item-title">Título 10</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-spacer">End scroll</div>



Please see this codepen.

This is probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218193/referenceerror-cant-access-lexical-declarationx-before-initialization and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone -

spaceHolder.style.height = \${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;-calcDynamicHeighttries to access the value ofpaddingRight, but you have not even set that at this point. Just move that line below the let paddingRight = gcs.getPropertyValue('--padding-right');` line.

@C3roe I tried your suggestion and the error disappeared but it creates another issue: on the front end, the horizontal scroll is endless.

Not really sure what that is supposed to mean to begin with, but you will have to do some more debugging then, I suppose.

@C3roe I edited the code. You can visualize the issue by scrolling the snippet. About the debugging, by the fact there is no error in the console I don't find the way to solve the issue.

I think your css custom property has no unit. 100 of what?

Debugging means more than just checking if there are any error messages, it also includes checking if the logic you implemented is correct or not. Inspecting the elements reveals <div class="c-scroll__wrapper js-scroll-wrapper" style="height: 4.4011e+06px;"> (actual value might vary, depending on your test browser's viewport size), and that massive height value is to blame for the "endless" scroll. So go check on your calculation of that value.

@DerAlex You're right I forgot to include the pixel unit (px). I just tried to include the px unit inside the css variable and the horizontal scroll doesn't work anymore.

maybe this is because the unit will then be used inside the javascript part. you can add the unit in css like this without adding it to the css custom property directly: padding: 0 0 0 calc(var(--padding-right) * 1px);

@MathieuPréaud Did these comments help you resolve your issue? If so consider adding an answer to your post so others can have it for reference. If not, what issues are you still facing and maybe we can offer more help?
