# what is the difference between these two functions (arrow function vs function declaration)

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

```
function pickColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}

let pickColor = () => {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}
```

when I try and call the second one, I get an error that says  "Cannot access 'pickColor' before initialization"

Comment: `let` is not hoisted.

Comment: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) + [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable). For further information: [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 1):

`let pickColor = ...` acts like a normal variable declaration + assignment.

The assignment `=` is done only when the actual line of code is executed.

You can call the function defined this way only if the call happens after the declaration, and in a visible scope.

On the contrary, `function()` definitions are completely 'hoisted', meaning they act like if they were defined on top of the JS block, and may be called "before" their definition.

Example inspired from http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html :

```js
isItHoisted();

function isItHoisted() {
    console.log("Yes! This function declaration acts the same as if it was declared _before_ the call.");
}


isThisOtherOneHoisted(); // throws an ReferenceError if used before it is  assigned 

let isThisOtherOneHoisted = () => console.log("Javascript sees that the name exists, but the assignment has not been done.");

/**
like :

There is this variable isThisOtherOneHoisted defined later, just so you know.
isThisOtherOneHoisted(); // error, variable does not even containt a function yet
isThisOtherOneHoisted = () => console.log(...)

*/
```

As additional details, javascript still "see" that it is used before it is intitialized, so that's why the error message is different than if you used a variable that doesn't exist at all.

The *declaration* is hoisted for any variable, but only the fact that the variable exist. The *assignments* with `=` is only executed where it is written.

Comment: Every declaration is hoisted. However, with `let` and `const` the variable is not initialised which leads to [the temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)

Comment: @VLAZ yes, thanks for pointing that out. I edited a bit the answer to try to make this point a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is due something called "hoisting".

Basically when you use `function`, JavaScript moves the function to the top of the scope, so you can access it before initialization. Using let does not do this.

```js
func_1();

function func_1() {
    console.log("Thing");
}


func_2(); // will cause an error

let func_2 = () => console.log("Thing");
```

Details: Everything is technically hoisted, but `let` and `const` don't initialise until you get to their line. If you used `var`, the variable would start off as `undefined`

```js
console.log(aa); //undefined
var aa = "hello";
console.log(aa); //hello

console.log(bb) // error
let bb = "hello";
```

Sidenotes (This part is not a solution to the above problem): 
1. You should use `const` instead of `let` because I don't imagine you will need to change the value of a function.
2. Another difference between these declarations, is the value of the keyword `this` (it's the same in this situation but it can be different). I won't explain it here, you will probably come across it if you do more Javascript so worth looking into.

Comment: I've tried changing the variable assignments on my arrow function to const and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion `const` wont fix your problem, the problem is that usinf `function` makes the function available before it is declared. If you want to use `const` or `let` you need to define the function before calling it. I'm simply saying `const` is better for functions in most cases

Comment: Thank you! This would mean just mean writing the function before calling it in the text editor right?

Comment: @RyanHeaux Yes, just like when you declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration

```
function pickColor(){...}
```

is moved to the top of the scope (hoisted first) along with any variables declared with `var`.

where as function expression declared with `let` is only accessed when the interpreter comes across that line of code.

Example -

```
let two = () => {
  console.log('something else');
}

var x = 'demo'
let y = 'demo123'

function one() {
  console.log('something');  
};

function three(){
  one();  
}
```

variable `x` , `function one(){...}` , `function three(){...}` are moved to the top of the scope as soon as the execution starts,

`x` is `undefined` until the line 
`x = 'demo'`
then 
`x` is assigned a value of `'demo'`.

Variable `y` is not initiated or assigned any value until the line

`let y = 'demo123'`

since `let` is used to initiate the variable, same goes for the function expression initiated with `let`.