# Temporal Dead Zone with Hoisting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am learning JavaScript and having trouble understanding Temporal Dead Zone along with Hoisting.
So tried the following example,

```js
let test1;
console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
let test2;
```

The output is as follows:

```
undefined
VM883:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: test2 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:13
```

[image]

From my understanding, "Hoisting" feature creates memory space for all variables declarations (var, let, const, function, class). So I believe, both `test1` and `test2` are read and allocated space by the compiler.

From my understanding, "Temporal Dead Zone" is specific to `let` & `const` keywords and they're not initialized as "undefined" when they're just declared. So when we access it before initialization, we get a Reference error. Hence, both `test1` and `test2` should have thrown Reference error.

But why was the reference error thrown only for `test2`? Since we have not declared both the variables, why was `test1` logged as undefined?

Comment: If you don't explicitly provide an initial value (`let foo = value;`) then the variable is still initialized to `undefined` (just not at "hoisting time", like `var` would be). You are accessing `test1` *after* it was declared.

Comment: `let test1` instantiates test1 with undefined, but it *is* defined, which is why there is no reference error for being not defined. Not being defined, and the value `undefined` are two different things.

Comment: There are a lot of posts about hoisting, the temporal dead zone, and `let`, `const`, etc.; Here are a couple that should be read to begin understanding: [Are variables declared with let or const hoisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/215552), [What is the temporal dead zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/215552)