# How to implement forEach loop for a javascript linked list

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6, linked-list

I have a **LinkedList** class in Javascript(ES6) which has all the related helper methods (like insert, remove, update etc). Additionally, I want to implement a reusable **forEach** loop that can be used to iterate over the linked list.

```
class LinkedList(){
   constructor(){
      //linked list
      this.list = null; 
   }
   //Inserting a node at the first position
   insertFirst(data) {
      let node = new Node(data);
      if (this.list) {
        node.next = this.list;
        this.list = node;
      }
      else {
        this.list = node;
      }
    }
   //...
   //Other helper methods...
   //...

   forEach(){
      //loop implementation goes here
   }
}

//Node class for creating a new Node
class Node {
  constructor(data, next = null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }
}
```

For instance, this is the linked list with 'n' nodes,

```
this.list = {
   data: 10,
   next: node1
};
let node1 = { 
   data: 20, 
   next: node2
};
let node2 = { 
   data: 20, 
   next: node3
};
So and so...
```

I should be able to iterate the list like an **array forEach** and perform any action at the node level, like below

```
const list = new LinkedList();

//inserted 10 nodes using list.insertFirst() method

list.forEach(node => { 
   console.log(node.data); 
});
```

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think `this.list` will actually reference `node1` properly as it is init after it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)?

Comment: you have omitted too much of the `LinkedList` class to provide any useful answer here.  There are many ways to implement a Linked List;  we might ***infer*** how you implemented yours based on your data, but without seeing the actual implementation, suggesting a way to iterate through would only be a **guess**.

Comment: I meant to show that, the first node has the reference of the second node like any linked list, not worried about the reference as this is a representation.

Comment: Do you really create nodes as plain objects? Or do you have a Node class? In order for us to give a useful answer it is important we know these implementation details.

Comment: Yes, I will update the Node class too here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define an iterator on the class. This way you can even iterate over the values with a `for..of` loop.

Then you can build the `forEach` method on top of that. But in many situations you'll find it easier to use the iterator instead of the `forEach` method, as you don't need to provide a callback function when using the iterator.

Here is how that could look:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(data, next=null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.list = null; 
    }
    insertFirst(data) {
        this.list = new Node(data, this.list);
        return this; // add this line to make the method chainable!
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // define the default iterator for this class
        let node  = this.list; // get first node
        while (node) {  // while we have not reached the end of the list
            yield node.data;  // ... yield the current node's data
            node = node.next; // and move to the next node
        }
    }
    forEach(cb) { // Takes a callback argument.
        // As this object has a default iterator (see above) we
        //    can use the following syntax to consume that iterator.
        // Call the callback for each yielded value.
        for (let data of this) cb(data);
    }
}

let list = new LinkedList;
// Insert a few values. We makde the insertFirst method chainable:
list.insertFirst(30).insertFirst(20).insertFirst(10);
// Pass console.log as callback to call for each data in the list
list.forEach(console.log);
// ... or just with the iterator:
for (let data of list) console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, Very useful implementation with the generator function. I have built the forEach loop on top of it. Would be helpful if you can add stepwise comments in the code.

Comment: I added some comments. Let me know if something is unclear.