# How does React's useEffect hook have access to all function expressions defined beneath it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a functional component in React like this:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => logSomething(), [])

  const logSomething = () => console.log('whats up');
  return (<div> hello </div>)
}
```

This function runs without any errors, and successfully logs out "whats up" in the console.

When I try the following, however, I get a TypeError:

```
export default function App() {

  useEffect(logSomething(), [])

  const logSomething = () => () => console.log('whats up');
  return (<div> hello </div>)
}
```

Similarly, I get a TypeError when I try this:

```
export default function App() {

  useEffect(logSomething, [])

  const logSomething = () => console.log('whats up');
  return (<div> hello </div>)
}
```

Why does the first example succeed, but the second and third example fail? Is the first function expression getting hoisted somehow? And if so, why aren't the other 2 function expressions being hoisted? Or is this just some quirk with how function references work in JavaScript?

Comment: I believe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/9287029

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second and third examples, you are attempting to use logSomething before it is defined. This results in a type error.

The first example works, because the anonymous function passed into useEffect isn't immediately called, and so it's okay that logSomething isn't defined yet. By the time that function is called, const logSomething has been defined and is in scope.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is due to the design of JavaScript itself, and has nothing to do with React or the `useEffect` hook.

Within a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), both `let` and `const` are hoisted, but are initialized only when the corresponding declaration statements are executed. The period between the hoisting and the initialization is commonly referred to as the *'[temporal dead zone (TDZ)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz)'*. Attempting to access variables in the TDZ raises a `ReferenceError`.

In your second and third example, although `logSomething` is declared within the same block, you attempt to access them *(Either by attempting to run the assigned function, or pass the assigned function's reference to `useEffect`)* before the initialization statement is executed, and thus you get an error. In the first example however, `logSomething` is accessed *within* the function passed to `useEffect` and by the time the function is executed, `logSomething` is already initialized. Thus, it works.

---

#### TL; DR

The first example works, because:

1. `logSomething` is declared within the same block scope as the function passed to `useEffect`, and is thus available within scope.
2. By the time the effect runs, `logSomething` declaration statement has already been executed, and thus you do not get a `ReferenceError` when you try to access `logSomething` *(Unlike in the other two cases)*

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198850/11129093) an excellent answer if you'd like to learn more about the TDZ.

Comment: Ok, so the main reason why the first example works is because useEffect is asynchronous in nature, and by the time it tries to call the arrow function I gave to it, the logSomething method exists. The other two examples fail because the logSomething function expression is currently in the "temporal dead zone", causing them to throw a TypeError when we attempt to access them within the block in the function. It would probably work the same way if "useEffect" was "setTimeout" or some other asynchronous method as well. That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, this would also work if say you created a function `foo` within the block instead of calling `useEffect`, then declare `logSomething`, and call `foo` in the next statement in the *same* block. You would not get an error here either, as `logSomething` would have been initialized by the time `foo` runs.