# Learning React - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Started today learning react and i ran into an issue that might be more JS related than actually react.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

function Counters() {
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 4 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 },
  ]);


  const handleDelete = (counterID) => {
    setCounters(counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== counterID));
  };

  const handleIncrement = (counterToBeUpdated) => {
    console.log(counters);
    const counters = [...counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counterToBeUpdated);
    counters[index] = { ...counterToBeUpdated };
    counters[index].value++;
    setCounters({ counters });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {counters.map((counter) => (
        <Counter
          key={counter.id}
          counter={counter}
          onDelete={handleDelete}
          onIncrement={handleIncrement}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counters;
```

When child component calls handleIncrement i get the Reference error of trying to access counters before it was initialized.

Comment: You have a few errors: this line `setCounters({ counters });` is wrong, counters is an array but you're changing it to an object. As for the reference error, you assign a local variable (that shadows the outer state) in the handleIncrement function, but you try to log it before assigning it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the temporal dead zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)

Comment: You've got counters everywhere: `const counters = [...counters];`. Do you want to spread the `counters` from the outer scope and assign it to the same variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you try to use a variable with the same name from the outer scope:
`const counters = [...counters];`

```js
const counters = [1, 2, 3];

function update() {
  const counters = [...counters];
}

update();
// => "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'counters' before initialization"
```

You don't even need to use new variables in your increment handler, you can use a `counters.map()` to iterate over the elements and update the value required. The returned array will be a new array, so you can pass it to your `setCounters()` function. Check the working demo below:

```js
function Counter({ counter, onDelete, onIncrement }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span style={{marginRight: '1rem'}}>{counter.value}</span>
      <button onClick={() => onIncrement(counter.id)}>Inc</button>
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(counter.id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counters() {
  const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, value: 4 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 },
  ]);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setCounters(counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== id));
  };

  const handleIncrement = (id) => {
    setCounters(
      counters.map((counter) =>
        counter.id === id ? { ...counter, value: counter.value + 1 } : counter
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {counters.map((counter) => (
        <Counter
          key={counter.id}
          counter={counter}
          onDelete={handleDelete}
          onIncrement={handleIncrement}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here is how you call `handleIncrement`.
It is called without arguments meaning that `counterToBeUpdated` will be undefined.

If you change `onIncrement={handleIncrement}` to `onIncrement={() => handleIncrement(counter.id)}`, that's half the battle.

The in `handleIncrement` you use `counters.indexOf(counterToBeUpdated)`. `Array.indexOf()` returns the array position of the value you pass as argument. Since you are looking for an object, and object equality is a [large topic](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html) in javascript i recommend you better use `Array.find()` here.

This is how you would find your object inside the array.

```
const counterToBeUpdated = counters.find((counter) => counter.id === counterToBeUpdated);
```

Since this method still leaves a lot to do (increment counter, create new array with counters, set this array as state), i'll show you a shortcut by using `Array.map()`:

```
const handleIncrement = (counterToBeUpdated) => {
  setCounters(counters.map((counter) => {
    if(counter.id === counterToBeUpdated){
      return {
        ...counter,
        value: counter.value + 1
      };
    } else {
      return counter;
    }
  });
};
```

`Array.map()` returns a *new* Array. The function you pass will be executed for every value in the array and you decide how the appropriate value in the new array shall look like.