# can arrow function gets hoisted in a class? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```js
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1;

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this), false);
    this.resize();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  }

  resize() {
    this.stageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    this.stageHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }

  animate = () => {
    this.test(); // ---> here!
  };

  test = () => {
    console.log('here!');
  };
}

window.onload = () => {
  new App();
};
```

An arrow function is not hoisted, only regular functions are hoisted. How come, inside animate function, can call this.test? Different behavior of arrow function in a class?

Answer (score 7):

Although arrow functions aren't hoisted, what you have here aren't *just* arrow functions - you're using *class fields* here, which are syntax sugar for assigning a value to the instance inside the constructor (at the beginning of the constructor, just after any `super` calls). Your code is equivalent to:

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.animate = () => {
      this.test(); // ---> here!
    };

    this.test = () => {
      console.log('here!');
    };
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // ...
  }
}
```

It's not an issue of hoisting.

First `this.animate` gets a function assigned to it. Then `this.test` gets a function assigned to it. Then, eventually, after a `requestAnimationFrame`, `this.animate` is called.

For a more minimal example of this:

```js
const fn1 = () => {
  fn2();
};
const fn2 = () => {
  console.log('fn2');
};

fn1();
```

As long as the line that assigns the function to the variable has run before the function gets called, everything should work.

Comment: ```
videoElem.addEventListener('canplaythrough', render);

const render = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(videoElem, 0, 0, 600, 400);

        ctx.font = '20px Bungee Outline';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
}
```

in this case, i got an error - then why is that?

Comment: @facVV Because, as CertainPerformance explained, arrow functions aren't hoisted (in the sense you mean), and what you see in the class is a different thing. However, this example has no class in it at all, so even if they may look similarly, they're different. For this example, refer to [TDZ (Temporal Dead Zone)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/8376184)

Comment: @CertainPerformance If I'm right, the problem with the code in facVV's comment is that the `render` variable (that contains an arrow function) is referenced earlier than it's defined...

Comment: @facVV You can't run a line that references a variable before the line that has initialized the line (with `const someVarName =`) has run.