# How is it possible an object has a property but access to it results in ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// a.js
import * as bModule from './b.js'
export const b = bModule

// b.js
import * as aModule from './a.js'
export const a = aModule
```

If `a.js` is an entry point of our app then `b.js` would run firstly. Calling of `console.log(aModule)` from `b.js` at this stage results in such output:

```
[Module] {
  b: <uninitialized>,
}
```

And if `b.js` try to access `aModule.b` it will end up with the `ReferenceError: b is not defined`.

`ReferenceError` is thrown when a code uses an identifier (variable) hasn't declared yet. However, in this case `aModule` does have the property `b` (the fact is borne out by `console.log`). Moreover, when we access an uninitialized object property we just get the `undefined` value but not the exception.

So how this behavior can be understood? Is it specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ReferenceError is thrown when a code uses an identifier (variable) hasn't declared yet.

Not *only* then. :-)

> Moreover, when we access an uninitialized object property we just get the undefined value but not the exception.

Yes, but modules are modern constructs, and you're using those another modern construct: `let`. It's defined to fail if used before it could be initialized, rather than provide ambiguous values.

Yes, it's specified behavior. Modules go through a series of phases, and during that process their exports of `let`, `const`, or `class` bindings are created as *uninitialized bindings*, and then later those exports are initialized with values. When modules have *cycles* (circular dependencies), it's possible to see an export before it's initialized, causing a `ReferenceError`.

It's the same Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ) we can see here:

```js
let a = 21;
console.log(a); // 21
if (true) {
    console.log(a); // ReferenceError
    let a = 42;
}
```

The declaration for `a` within the `if` block declares it throughout the block, but you can't *access* it until the declaration is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. You can see that the declaration takes effect throughout the block by the fact that we can't access the outer `a` from inside the block.

The same TDZ applies to exports that haven't been initialized yet.

You'll only have this problem with top-level code in a module, since the module graph will be fully resolved before any callbacks occur. Your code in `b.js` would be safe using `a.b` in a function called in response to an event (or called from `a.js`).

If you needed to use `a.b` in `b.js` at the top level, you'd need to run the call after `b.js`'s top-level code execution was complete, which you can do via `setTimeout` or similar:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(a.b); // Shows the `b` module namespace object's contents
}, 0);
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into the mechanics of modules, including the TDZ and cycles, in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* (the TDZ in relation to `let`, `const`, and `class` is in Chapters 2 and 4). Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is because of the [`temporal dead zone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone).

Unlike identifiers declared using `var`, identifiers declared using `let` or `const` are marked as "not yet initialized" and they can't be accessed until their declaration has actually executed during step-by-step execution of the javascript code.

Since `b` in `a.js` is defined with `const`, it is *hoisted* but you can't access it before its declaration has actually executed. Same would be the case if `b` was declared with `let`.

If you declare `b` using `var`, then you would see `undefined` as the output.