# Call a functional component in React before it is declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hoisting

```
const ShowHide = () => {
   return <Item/>;
};

const Item = () => {
   return(
     //few lines of code
   );
};
```

Here, the functional component ShowHide calls component 'Item'.
Item is an arrow function and it is not hoisted.

How is it possible to call Item before it is declared?

Comment: `ShowHide` is called after `Item` is defined, and javascript doesn't care otherwise. Tl;dr; `const f = () => x; const x = 'something';` doesn't throw, but `const f = () => x; f(); const x = 'something';` does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the temporal dead zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone)

Comment: You could just use `function` instead of arrow functions assigned to `const` variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response.How is ShowHide called after Item definition?

Comment: In your code, it is actually never called, but obvious, that it won't be called before `Item` is defined.

Comment: Thank you somuch

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible to call Item before it is declared?

It's imposible. Read this: [javascript variables and temporal dead zone](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-variables-and-temporal-dead-zone/)

You can define Item in other file, and imports to file with ShowHide component. It's all what you can do.

Comment: Yes it works, and reason is ShowHide is called after Item is defined

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what `ASDFGerte` commented.

The following would not work:

```js
const ShowHide = () => {
   return Item();
};

console.log(ShowHide());
const Item = () => {
   return 'hello world'
};
```

Because you are trying to use a const before it's defined and as you can see it won't be hoisted.

The following will work:

```js
const ShowHide = () => {
   return Item();
};
const Item = () => {
   return 'hello world'
};
console.log(ShowHide());
```

Because by the time `ShowHide` is called and `Item` is needed it is already defined.

Comment: Thankyou. The code snippet is used in React and 'Showhide' is exported to app.js.I am not sure how the execution of 'ShowHide' happens in app.js after defining 'Item'.Appreciate your help.