# Are ES Modules evaluated to their very end before export?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want be able to export and then modify a object. However I am not sure if this is unexpected behavior.

test.js:

```
// Short syntax
export const foo = [];
foo[0] = 1;

// Long syntax
const bar = [];
bar[0] = 1;
export { bar };
```

index.js:

```
import { foo, bar } from "./test.js";

console.log("foo:" + foo); // Is it guaranteed to be [1]? Or can it be []?
console.log("bar:" + bar); // I always expect this to be [1].
```

This might be a foolish example but sometimes I have an object and want to register some methods/properties. I want to know if I am able to export it and then register them.

Comment: Read: [export default thing` is different to `export { thing as default }](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/export-default-thing-vs-thing-as-default/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are ES modules evaluated to their very end before export?

No. In fact, the exports are declared and registered *before* the module is evaluated.

However, what you actually seem to be asking is

> Are ES modules evaluated to their very end before the modules importing them are evaluated?

Yes. *test.js* will be fully evaluated before *index.js* is evaluated<sup>1</sup>. It doesn't matter where in the module you place the `import` and `export` declarations.

<sub>1: with the exception of circular dependencies. In that case, a module might run before all the imported modules are evaluated, and you may run into [uninitialised variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572).</sub>

> Is it guaranteed to be `[1]`? Or can it be `[]`?

Yes, it's guaranteed to be `[1]` (or an exception that `const foo` is not yet initialised). It will never be `[]`, the `= []` and the `foo[0] = 1` always execute right after each other.