# Why it's impossible to reassign global name within local scope (without `global` keyword) with using the global name's value in reassignment?

Tags: python, scope

If we run this code

```
a = 1

def foo():
    b = a + 2
    print(b)
    
foo()
```

it works. 
But if we run this code

```
a = 1

def foo():
    b = a + 2
    print(b)
    
    a = a + 4
    print(a)
foo()
```

it doesn't work. 

Question: 
why in the first example `b = a + 2` works without errors but in the second example the same line of code `b = a + 2` is broken? 
why if there is no reassignment of `a` we can get `a` from a global scope but if there is a reassignment we don't have an access to `a` even if new local `a` doesn't even exist yet (because the reassignment isn't finished).

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude an error emerges: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: Why [...] the first example works without errors but in the second example the same line of code is broken?

Because in the first example, you're only reading from a global `a`, then writing to a local `b`.

In the second example, `a` is assumed to be a local too (since you're not declaring `global a`), and it has no value when you're trying to read it in the first line, hence an error.

This is similar to [JavaScript's Temporal Dead Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone), if that's familiar.

As for the question in your title:

> Why it's impossible to reassign global name within local scope (without `global` keyword) with using the global name's value in reassignment?

You're not reassigning
a global name at all in either of your examples, since indeed you're not using the `global` keyword. In Python, you can always read a global (or "ambient") name; otherwise it'd be a pain to e.g. use any builtin function (since they're not locals), and having a special exception for builtins would be, well, a special exception, and those aren't nice.