# Best way to loop through an array and return the sub arrays that match the first 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

Let's say I have 4 arrays:

```
var arrays =  [
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 2]
];
```

And I want to return the child/sub arrays that start with both 1 and 2, what type of loop would I need?

Currently, this is what I have:

```
var arrays =  [
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 2]
];
        
var selected = [1, 2]; // These are the values that need to match
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
        if (arrays[i][j] === selected[i]) {
            result.push(arrays[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When there's more than 1 value in the `selected` array, it seems to return all the ones that match 2 on the second index, so the result would be:

```
[
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 2]
]
```

The loop needs to ensure that on the second iteration it's making sure the first value is still true, as my intended result would be:

```
[
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 3]
]
```

Please someone help me, I've had my head trying hundreds of different loop and checks variations for 2-3 days.

Thanks so much!!

Jake

Comment: You need to iterate over `selected` for every sub-array, so your loops should be reversed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach where you turn both arrays to string and check it those inner arrays start with selected array.

```js
var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2, 2]
];

var selected = [1, 2];
const result = arrays.filter(e => e.toString().startsWith(selected.toString()))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that while this works for numbers-only arrays, it may not always work for strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code pushes to the result array whenever any given index matches between `arrays` and `selected`. Instead you will need to reverse your loops and iterate over `selected` for every sub array and check if every element matches, if not `break` the inner loop and don't push.

```js
const arrays = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2, 2],
];

const selected = [1, 2]; // These are the values that need to match
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  let match = true;
  for (let j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
    if (arrays[i][j] !== selected[j]) {
      match = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (match) {
    result.push(arrays[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

A more modern solution would be to use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a nested [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) call on `selected`.

```js
const arrays = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2, 2],
];

var selected = [1, 2];
const result = arrays.filter(arr => selected.every((n, i) => n === arr[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to put your condition into words. That way, an implementation may come to mind more easily.

A short wording may be: "Take all arrays that match (rather: start with) a certain sub-array." In code, it may look like this:

```js
const arrays = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2, 2]
];
const selection = [1, 2];

const result = filterArrays(arrays, selection);
console.log(result);

function filterArrays(arrays, selection) {
  const selectedArrays = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; ++i) {
    const array = arrays[i];
    const subarray = array.slice(0, selection.length); // Get starting sub-array
    if (compareArrays(subarray, selection)) {
      selectedArrays.push(array);
    }
  }
  
  return selectedArrays;
}

/*Ignore; helper function*/
function compareArrays(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) return false;
  
  const length = array1.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important}
```

Another, more specific wording may be: "Take all arrays that match a selection at an index." Note that we only reworded the "match a sub-array" part. I believe this is what you tried.

Refer to [pilchard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74724281/13561410) for an implementation. Note that their implementation assumes the arrays in `arrays` to be *at least* the same length as `selected`.

---

I see you used [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) instead of the *preferred* modern [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) declarators. Here's a short outline of their differences:

- `let`/`const` declarators:

  - Block-scoped.

    - Narrower scope means less name-space pollution.
  - More similar to declarators in other well-known languages:

    - Variables of these declarators cannot be used before their declaration (see [TDZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198850/13561410)).
- `var` declarator:

  - Function-scoped.
  - [Hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and with no TDZ, resulting in this (perhaps confusing) behaviour:

    - Variables declared with `var` can be used even before their declaration.
    - Duplicate declarations are allowed since they are effectively the same.

Also, JavaScript has different kinds of for-loops:

- [`for`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for): The for-loops you used are this kind. It is the most versatile kind.
- [`for...of`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of): A loop to iterate over an *iterable* object (see [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterators)). For example, arrays are iterable, so you can get its values with a `for...of`-loop:

  ```js
  const values = [1, 2, 3];
  let sum = 0;
  for (const value of array) {
    sum += value;
  }
  console.log(sum); // -> 6
  ```
- [`for...in`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): A loop to iterate over [*enumerable* properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object. It is easily confused with a `for...of`-loop, but [MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#difference_between_for...of_and_for...in) demonstrates the differences understandably.

In my code example above, the `for`-loop in `filterArrays()` can be replaced with a `for...of`-loop to better convey my intention: To iterate over all arrays in `arrays`, disregarding their index:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; ++i) {
  const array = arrays[i];
  // ...
}
// Same as
for (const array of arrays) {
  // ...
}
```