# The js file builded by Rollup can't give the right order

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollup

I create a typescript project and use Rollup to build it, but error:

[image: 1]

and then I find this bug in the builded file carefully, and discover the class `Text` has defined before class `Carobj`

```js
var newcar = (function (exports){
  // ......
  class Text extends Carobj {
    // ......
  }
  
  class Carobj {
    // ......
  }
})({})
```

So how to make class `Carobj` in front of `Text` when use Rollup to build project?

I wanna Rollup can use right order to build codes.

Comment: How do your source files look? Especially their imports and exports?

Comment: Does your project work if you execute the modules directly without bundling? Do you have any circular dependencies?

Comment: @Bergi The source code about this bug is a little huge, so if you don't mind, visit https://github.com/Bug-Duck/newcar/tree/develop. and I use rollup to build `packages/core`, The export code was in index.ts

Comment: I found the [*index.ts*](https://github.com/Bug-Duck/newcar/blob/develop/packages/core/src/index.ts) that you are using as the entry point, but where are `CarObj` and `Text`? All you need to add to your question are the `import` and `export` declarations of the involved modules, you can omit the body of all the `class` definitions (just how you did it in the snippet of the output).

Comment: @Bergi `Carobj` and `Text` is in the `packages/objects`, I use pnpm to create a monorepo, in `packages/core`, the `import` and `export` declaration like this: `import {Carobj} from "@newcar/core" // ...... export {Carobj}; export {Text} from "@newcar/objects"`

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include those details as formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between [the module exporting `CarObj` and re-export `Text` (*index.ts*)](https://github.com/Bug-Duck/newcar/blob/ef27a6a9d559d6bd1d02f612a5d046fc9b064ccb/packages/objects/src/index.ts) and [the module importing `CarObj` and exporting `Text` (*text.ts*)](https://github.com/Bug-Duck/newcar/blob/ef27a6a9d559d6bd1d02f612a5d046fc9b064ccb/packages/objects/src/lib/text.ts).

When you attempt to import anything from *index.ts* (like your entrypoint does) - it doesn't matter whether that's `CarObj` or `Text` or nothing - then it will first load *index.ts*, then load its dependencies, including *text.ts*, which in turn loads its dependencies that were not already loaded.  After all variables are declared and imports/exports are set up, when all of *text.ts*' dependencies are met - again excluding *index.ts* which is already in the process of being imported - it is executed, attempting to initialise the `class Text`, and runs into an error because the `CarObj` it attempts to extend is still in the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572). If it had finished, the *index.ts* module could have been executed after all its dependencies were met, and so on, back until the entry point.

So this is not a problem of rollup, it just bundles the code in the same order, with the same scopes, as it would have been executed with individual modules. Which leads to the same exception.

The fix is simple: put the `class CarObj` into a separate module, and import only that in *text.ts*, not the *index.ts* that imports *text.ts*.

```js
// index.ts
export { CarObj } from "./lib/obj";
export { Text } from "./lib/text";
```

```js
// lib/obj.ts
export class CarObj {
  …
}
```

```js
// lib/text.ts
import { CarObj } from "./obj";
//                     ^^^^^^^ - not "../index"!
export class Text extends CarObj {
  …
}
```

Comment: But I need use `Carobj` as a type, so I must import it in `index.ts`, what should I do?

Comment: Sure you can import and re-export the `CarObj` in *index.ts*, you just must not import that one into the *text.ts*. (Or you can, if it's only `import type …`, which will get stripped out and not actually loaded/executed).

Comment: Okay, now the bug has been fixed!