# zod TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, circular-dependency, vitest

I have a Vite library using Vitest and Zod. Given the following folder structure

```
.
├── src
│   ├── leading
│   │   ├── index.ts ( 2 )
│   │   └── leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts
│   ├── index.ts ( 1 )
│   └── dataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts
└── test
    └── my.spec.ts
```

I created a base schema for data sources

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const dataSourceConfigurationSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string().min(1)
}).strict();

export { dataSourceConfigurationSchema };
```

exported by the index.ts ( 1 )

```
export * from "./leading";
export { dataSourceConfigurationSchema } from "./dataSourceConfigurationSchema";
```

I also have a schema extending the one above

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import { dataSourceConfigurationSchema } from '..';

const leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema = dataSourceConfigurationSchema.extend({
    entityTypeId: z.string().min(1),
}).strict();

export { leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema };
```

the index.ts ( 2 ) only exports this schema

```
export { leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema } from "./leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema";
```

When creating a test file like so

```
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import { ZodError } from 'zod';
import { leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema } from '../src';

describe('test', () => {
  it('fails.', () => {
    expect(() => leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema.parse({})).toThrow(ZodError);
  });
});
```

the test fails with the following error message

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

This problem might be related to

- https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1193
- https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/654

When replacing the import

> import { dataSourceConfigurationSchema } from '..';

with

> import { dataSourceConfigurationSchema } from '../dataSourceConfigurationSchema';

the test passes. So it seems the project is struggling with circular dependencies?

Do sub directories have to import files directly or can I fix this problem with a different approach?

Comment: wheres the code for leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a circular dependency, and due to the import order `dataSourceConfigurationSchema` will not yet be initialised when `leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema` is intialised. This is not an issue of zod or vite (although with a proper ES6 module implementation, you'd get a [TDZ error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572) instead of a reference error from accessing a method on `undefined`).

As you saw, you can fix this by importing `dataSourceConfigurationSchema` directly from *../dataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts* and not from *../index.ts*, the module that imports *leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts* itself.

Another solution would be to change the order of imports in *src/index.ts* to

```
export { dataSourceConfigurationSchema } from "./dataSourceConfigurationSchema";
export * from "./leading";
```

but this is really fragile, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: changing the order worked for me, thanks!