# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'setTimeout' before initialization

Tags: javascript

In my code I am trying to do a javascript exercise. On the second line, I'm trying to get the ogTimeout to store a reference to setTimeout function since I will reassign a new definition to setTimeout.

However I get the error "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'setTimeout' before initialization". I understand that it's saying that setTimeout should be initialized, but it already is a existing function, so I don't understand what's causing the error.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

```js
const timeouts = [];
const ogTimeout = setTimeout; 

let setTimeout = function(method, timeInMs) {
    const timeoutRef = ogTimeout(method, timeInMs);
    timeouts.push(timeoutRef);
}

const clearAllTimeouts = function() {
    while (timeouts.length) {
        const timeoutRef = timeouts.pop();
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
    }
}

setTimeout(() => console.log("Callback after 5 seconds."), 5000);
```

Tried searching referenceerror and its details.

Comment: try `const ogTimeout = globalThis.setTimeout;`

Comment: @Ima this is due to whats called hoisting, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: @ug_ variables declared using let/const are not hoisted

Comment: @JaromandaX Sure they are, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572

Comment: @JaromandaX Its in the docs. "let, const, and class declarations (also collectively called lexical declarations) are hoisted with type 3 behavior"... "3. The declaration of the variable causes behavior changes in its scope before the line in which it is declared."

They arent hoisted in the traditional sense of what people think of with hosting. However their use in a scope causes behavior changes according to hoisting documentation

Comment: `They arent hoisted in the traditional sense of what people think of with hosting` that's the part I was referring to - but I get your point :p it is the reason the OP had the error (that and the *temporal dead zone*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's saying that setTimeout should be initialized, but it already is a existing function

No, it's the `let setTimeout` that you declared yourself, which is not yet initialised when `const ogTimeout = setTimeout` runs. Accessing it during the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572) causes this error.

> I will reassign a new definition to setTimeout.

To overwrite the global `setTimeout`, don't declare your own variable. Remove the `let` and write only

```
setTimeout = function(method, timeInMs) {
    const timeoutRef = ogTimeout(method, timeInMs);
    timeouts.push(timeoutRef);
};
```

Or to be even more explicit, you can also assign to the property of the global `window` object:

```
window.setTimeout = function(method, timeInMs) {
    const timeoutRef = ogTimeout(method, timeInMs);
    timeouts.push(timeoutRef);
};
```

Btw for this to not break any code, do not forget to also `return timeoutRef` from your function.