# What is difference between hoisting var x = 3 and var x

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

Consider the two following snippets

```js
function x(){}
var x = 3;
console.log(typeof x) //"number"
```

This happens because function declarations are hoisted first.

```js
function x(){}
var x;
console.log(typeof x) //"function"
```

I expect the type to be `undefined` because `var x;` creates a variable with `undefined` value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redeclaring a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888506/redeclaring-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`var x` declares the variable `x`but doesn't assign anything to it.

If you did set its value to `undefined`, then that would be `undefined`:

```js
function x(){}
var x = undefined;
console.log(typeof x) //"undefined"
```

So what you made in your example is just

```
var x;
function x(){}
```

While in my example it becomes

```
var x;
function x(){}
x = undefined;
```

Comment: `var x` should implicitly assign `undefined` to `x` even if there's no intentional assignment, the problem is on the order of hoisting of functions and variables, not the assignment

Comment: @jackz314 the point is the difference between *assignment* and *declaration* Variables are **always** undefined when declared, but only if they have an **assigned** value function *declaration* won't override it. Because the order is variable declaration, function declarations then script execution which may perform variable assignment.

Comment: I guess we are on the same page since we both agree that the order is the problem, but the way you answered it made it sound like assignment's problem, it could be just me though.

Comment: Yes, the assignment is the problem. Since if there is no assignment then there is nothing after the function's declaration, while when there is assignment, it will get executed after.

Comment: I know, and this happens because of the order you mentioned, I think it's just I misinterpreted the way you parsed it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

its because of that in first section you set x as new variable with type of number,in another words, var x=3 is override on x and has type of number because of 3
but in second section, you just call x, and say it is variable that has type of function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in JavaScript, if a function and a variable with the same name and scope are declared, they are hoisted like so:

If the variable has a value, or gets a value at any point, it is hoisted to the top and takes precedence.
If the variable is created but has an `undefined` value (e.g. `var x;`), then the function takes precedence.

This does **not** happen when you explicitly set a value to `undefined`, like `var x = undefined`

That's why this happens (it *gets a value at any point*)

```js
function x() {}
var x;
x = 4;
console.log(typeof x);
```

Same here - even with odd variable and function placement, because the variable gets the value:

```js
var x;
function x() {}
x = 5;
console.log(typeof x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variables won't override existing variables.

```js
var x = 111;
var x;
console.log(typeof x);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules for hoisting are:

1. Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration
2. Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations

So the order of the hoisting would be

```
Variable declaration -> Function declaration -> Variable assignment
```

Take a look at this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript), basically, to quote the article, the reason this is happening is because:

> Function declarations are hoisted over variable declarations but not over variable assignments.

In this [section](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-order-of-precedence), it even has the exact same example as you gave in your question.

To sum up, your declaration of function x can't "overwrite" (hoist over) your variable assignment, but can "overwrite" your variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The x returns the type of function, because

"In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects."

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Basically you have created 2 objects referencing the same name `x` and because `var x` is not given any kind of value, the function is returned as it is taking precedence over unassigned variable.

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript, an undeclared variable is assigned the value undefined at execution and is also of type undefined.**

```
var a;
typeof a; //"undefined"
```