# Arrow function in javascript output?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I was learning about arrow function in js where I found one question

```js
console.log((function(x, f = () => x) {
  var x;
  var y = x;
  x = 2;
  return [x, y, f()];
})(1));
```

It's output is `2,1,1` but it should be `1,1,1`.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Because, `x = 2;`

Comment: Can you explain why you expect the first element in the result to be `1`?  Or what this even has to do with arrow functions at all, since the only difference in the result isn't produced by an arrow function?  If the only difference you're seeing from observed vs. expected results is the first value in the response, simplify the code and refactor out anything unrelated to that first value.  What do you end up with?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl f = () => x what does it mean?

Comment: Are you asking why `console.log([2, 1, 1])` prints `2, 1, 1` instead of `1, 1, 1`?

Comment: @David Why the value of y is 1?

Comment: Or instead of `2, 1, 2` since `f()` returns `x`

Comment: Because you set y = x before reassigning x

Comment: You are confused because the code snippet you shared is using `Variable shadowing`

Comment: @Deepak_8097: Because when you did this: `var y = x;` the value of `x` *at that time* was `1`.

Comment: _"Why the value of y is 1?"_ Because `var y = x;` is a copy. Changing `x` won't change `y`.

Comment: @jabaa I am confused with f = () => x this syntax?

Comment: How is the third element of the array related to the first element? _"It's output is `2,1,1` but it should be `1,1,1`."_ The only difference between your expected output and the actual output is the first element of the array, the value of `x`. It's unrelated to `f = () => x`. Why do you expect the first element to be `1`?

Comment: if you don't pass a second parameter, that parameter is a function returning `x`

Comment: Does this help: https://jsfiddle.net/uzL4n3p1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function re-written to show what is happening.

1. `main` takes `x` = `1`
2. `defaultFunction` returns the original `x` = `1`
3. `resultFn` is a function that gets called inside of `main` that takes `x`
4. `y` is assigned the `x` that was passed all the way down (local -scope) `1`
5. `x` is reassigned to `2`
6. The result is `2, 1, 1`

This is an exercise on variable/parameter scope.

```js
const main = (x) => {                      // x = 1
  const defaultFn = () => x;               // x = 1
  const resultFn = (x, f = defaultFn) => { // x = 1
    var x;                                 // x is still 1
    var y = x;                             // y = 1
    x = 2;                                 // x = 2
    return [x, y, f()];                    // x = 2, y = 1, f() -> 1
  };
  return resultFn(x);                      // 2, 1, 1
};

console.log(main(1));
```

Comment: At least for me this behavior is very confusing. I expected `var x;` to introduce a new, uninitialized variable that shadows the parameter `x`. I was surprised that `y` was set to `1` and not `undefined`. With this question and your answer I learned that `var x;` is a redeclaration and `let x;` causes an error.

Comment: @jabaa see: [Redeclaring a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888506/redeclaring-a-javascript-variable) (var specific, ah hoisting)

Comment: @pilchard Yes, I got it after some testing and reading but I was surprised. JavaScript can be confusing. It's great that `var` was replaced with `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You set x to 2 thus it got returned as 2. Change x to 1.
Fixed Code:

```
console.log((function(x, f = () => x) {
  var x;
  var y = x;
  x = 2;
  return [x, y, f()];
})(1));
```

Comment: What does it mean f = () => x?

Comment: @Deepak_8097 `() => x` defines an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and `f = () => x` assigns this function to `f`.

Comment: it assigns it *if* no parameter is passed.

Comment: This is a tricky [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) situation.

Comment: @MXCDR _"it assigns x to f"_. No, it doesn't. `x` contains a number. `f` contains a function.

Comment: @jabaa Okay it is an arrow function and it is returning the value of x.

Comment: @Deepak_8097 Yes, it's a function that reads the value of a copy of `x` and returns it. It doesn't change any variable. So it's still unclear why you expect `x` to equal `1` after `x = 2;`.